# How to combine paths in Java?

Tags: java, path

Is there a Java equivalent for [`System.IO.Path.Combine()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx) in C#/.NET? Or any code to accomplish this?

This static method combines one or more strings into a path.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204784/how-to-construct-a-relative-path-in-java-from-two-absolute-paths-or-urls) SO question might help.

Answer (score 506):

Rather than keeping everything string-based, you should use a class which is designed to represent a file system path.

If you're using Java 7 or Java 8, you should strongly consider using [`java.nio.file.Path`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html); `Path.resolve` can be used to combine one path with another, or with a string. The [`Paths`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html) helper class is useful too. For example:

```
Path path = Paths.get("foo", "bar", "baz.txt");
```

If you need to cater for pre-Java-7 environments, you can use [`java.io.File`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html), like this:

```
File baseDirectory = new File("foo");
File subDirectory = new File(baseDirectory, "bar");
File fileInDirectory = new File(subDirectory, "baz.txt");
```

If you want it back as a string later, you can call `getPath()`. Indeed, if you really wanted to mimic `Path.Combine`, you could just write something like:

```
public static String combine(String path1, String path2)
{
    File file1 = new File(path1);
    File file2 = new File(file1, path2);
    return file2.getPath();
}
```

Comment: Beware of absolute paths.  The .NET version will return `path2` (ignoring `path1`) if `path2` is an absolute path.  The Java version will drop the leading `/` or `\ ` and treat it as a relative path.

Comment: To satisfy @finnw [important] comment you can add `File f2 = new File(path2); if (f2.isAbsolute()) return f2;` somewhere in your function.

Comment: This is inefficient and unclean, as it requires creating a File object, and then back to string.

Comment: @Hugo: So it wastes a whole *two objects*? Shocking! Looks pretty clean to me, to be honest... it keeps the *logic* for relative file names where it belongs, in the File class.

Comment: still, I'd argue that a constructor `new File(String... pathElements)` would be cleaner, possible with an added `new File(File basepath, String... pathElements)`

Comment: new File("a/b/c", "../c2") yields "a/b/c/../c2". How do I get "a/b/c2" instead?

Comment: @modosansreves: Look at `File.getCanonicalPath`.

Comment: @SargeBorsch: Well C# is just a language. You could easily create your own equivalent of `File` in C# if you wanted to. (I'm assuming you mean the existence of `File` is a benefit, which I'd agree with.)

Comment: @SargeBorsch: These days, Java works more with `Path` objects than with `File`... but in .NET, there's always `FileInfo` and `DirectoryInfo` if you want. Regardless, this isn't a matter for C#, given that it's only a language...

Comment: Using objects for file names is unnecessarily messy. Evidence: trying to work with them in PowerShell. I'm constantly having to convert to strings so I can pass it to some command line tool, and I end up with a bunch of boiler plate just trying to get it to spit out the right string especially since there are a bunch of different types that can be used for file objects. I used to think you "should use an object," too, but there's no real gain that I've ever seen.

Comment: @jpmc26: That's only evidence of it being a pain in a specific setting. I've found it very useful in Java for a variety of other needs which *don't* require the value as a string.

Answer (score 192):

In Java 7, you should use [`resolve`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#resolve(java.nio.file.Path)):

```
Path newPath = path.resolve(childPath);
```

While the NIO2 Path class may seem a bit redundant to File with an unnecessarily different API, it is in fact subtly more elegant and robust.

Note that `Paths.get()` (as suggested by someone else) doesn't have an overload taking a `Path`, and doing `Paths.get(path.toString(), childPath)` is NOT the same thing as `resolve()`. From the [`Paths.get()` docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html#get(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String...)):

> Note that while this method is very convenient, using it will imply an assumed reference to the default FileSystem and limit the utility of the calling code. Hence it should not be used in library code intended for flexible reuse. A more flexible alternative is to use an existing Path instance as an anchor, such as:
>
> ```
> Path dir = ...
> Path path = dir.resolve("file");
> ```

The sister function to `resolve` is the excellent [`relativize`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#relativize(java.nio.file.Path)):

```
Path childPath = path.relativize(newPath);
```

Comment: "Note that while this method is very convenient, using it will imply an assumed reference to the default FileSystem and limit the utility of the calling code."

Sure, but you have to use some equivalent function to generate a Path object (because it's an interface and can't be instantiated directly). So at some point you are creating a reference to the underlying FS. I think the docs are misleading here.

Comment: @éclairevoyant They mean the reference will be to the *default* FS, rather than the FS that the parent path refers to. Unlike most OSes, Java supports multiple, separate filesystems. Eg, a zip file or cloud storage can be exposed as a FS object. It’s a cool, although not-widely-used-yet feature.

Comment: All modern OSes should support multiple filesystems, but that's besides the point. If not `Paths.get(...)` how would one create a `Path` without using an existing `Path`? (Maybe this should be a new question.)

Comment: @éclairevoyant `FileSystem::getPath` I should have said Java supports multiple FS *namespaces* (one per FS object). OSes have a single namespace.

Answer (score 47):

The main answer is to use File objects. However [Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/) does have a class [FilenameUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html) that can do this kind of thing, such as the [concat()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html#concat%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method.

Comment: FilenameUtils.concat, to be precise. http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html#concat%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29

Comment: If youre working with something like JSF, youre definitly want to keep it String-based as all the Paths you 'll get will be String-based.

Answer (score 28):

platform independent approach (uses File.separator, ie will works depends on operation system where code is running:

```
java.nio.file.Paths.get(".", "path", "to", "file.txt")
// relative unix path: ./path/to/file.txt
// relative windows path: .\path\to\filee.txt

java.nio.file.Paths.get("/", "path", "to", "file.txt")
// absolute unix path: /path/to/filee.txt
// windows network drive path: \\path\to\file.txt

java.nio.file.Paths.get("C:", "path", "to", "file.txt")
// absolute windows path: C:\path\to\file.txt
```

Answer (score 18):

I know its a long time since Jon's original answer, but I had a similar requirement to the OP.

By way of extending Jon's solution I came up with the following, which will take one or more path segments takes as many path segments that you can throw at it.

**Usage**

```
Path.combine("/Users/beardtwizzle/");
Path.combine("/", "Users", "beardtwizzle");
Path.combine(new String[] { "/", "Users", "beardtwizzle", "arrayUsage" });
```

**Code here for others with a similar problem**

```
public class Path {
    public static String combine(String... paths)
    {
        File file = new File(paths[0]);

        for (int i = 1; i < paths.length ; i++) {
            file = new File(file, paths[i]);
        }

        return file.getPath();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

To enhance JodaStephen's answer, Apache Commons IO has FilenameUtils which does this.  Example (on Linux):

```
assert org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils.concat("/home/bob", "work\\stuff.log") == "/home/bob/work/stuff.log"
```

It's platform independent and will produce whatever separators your system needs.

Answer (score 6):

Late to the party perhaps, but I wanted to share my take on this. I prefer not to pull in entire libraries for something like this. Instead, I'm using a Builder pattern and allow conveniently chained `append(more)` calls.  It even allows mixing `File` and `String`, and can  easily be extended to support `Path` as well.  Furthermore, it automatically handles the different path separators correctly on both Linux, Macintosh, etc.

```
public class Files  {
    public static class PathBuilder {
        private File file;

        private PathBuilder ( File root ) {
            file = root;
        }

        private PathBuilder ( String root ) {
            file = new File(root);
        }

        public PathBuilder append ( File more ) {
            file = new File(file, more.getPath()) );
            return this;
        }

        public PathBuilder append ( String more ) {
            file = new File(file, more);
            return this;
        }

        public File buildFile () {
            return file;
        }
    }

    public static PathBuilder buildPath ( File root ) {
        return new PathBuilder(root);
    }

    public static PathBuilder buildPath ( String root ) {
        return new PathBuilder(root);
    }
}
```

Example of usage:

```
File root = File.listRoots()[0];
String hello = "hello";
String world = "world";
String filename = "warez.lha"; 

File file = Files.buildPath(root).append(hello).append(world)
              .append(filename).buildFile();
String absolute = file.getAbsolutePath();
```

The resulting `absolute` will contain something like:

```
/hello/world/warez.lha
```

or maybe even:

```
A:\hello\world\warez.lha
```

Answer (score 4):

If you do not need more than strings, you can use [com.google.common.io.Files](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/17.0/api/docs/com/google/common/io/Files.html)

```
Files.simplifyPath("some/prefix/with//extra///slashes" + "file//name")
```

to get

```
"some/prefix/with/extra/slashes/file/name"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution which handles multiple path parts and edge conditions:

```
public static String combinePaths(String ... paths)
{
  if ( paths.length == 0)
  {
    return "";
  }

  File combined = new File(paths[0]);

  int i = 1;
  while ( i < paths.length)
  {
    combined = new File(combined, paths[i]);
    ++i;
  }

  return combined.getPath();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This also works in Java 8 :

```
Path file = Paths.get("Some path");
file = Paths.get(file + "Some other path");
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution offers an interface for joining path fragments from a String[] array. It uses **java.io.File.File(String parent, String child)**:

```
    public static joinPaths(String[] fragments) {
        String emptyPath = "";
        return buildPath(emptyPath, fragments);
    }

    private static buildPath(String path, String[] fragments) {
        if (path == null || path.isEmpty()) {
            path = "";
        }

        if (fragments == null || fragments.length == 0) {
            return "";
        }

        int pathCurrentSize = path.split("/").length;
        int fragmentsLen = fragments.length;

        if (pathCurrentSize <= fragmentsLen) {
            String newPath = new File(path, fragments[pathCurrentSize - 1]).toString();
            path = buildPath(newPath, fragments);
        }

        return path;
    }
```

Then you can just do:

```
String[] fragments = {"dir", "anotherDir/", "/filename.txt"};
String path = joinPaths(fragments);
```

Returns:

```
"/dir/anotherDir/filename.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all given paths are absolute paths. you can follow below snippets to merge these paths.

```
String baseURL = "\\\\host\\testdir\\";
String absoluteFilePath = "\\\\host\\testdir\\Test.txt";;
String mergedPath = Paths.get(baseURL, absoluteFilePath.replaceAll(Matcher.quoteReplacement(baseURL), "")).toString();
```

output path is \\host\testdir\Test.txt.