# Java equivalent of Perl's File::Spec->catfile?

Tags: java, perl, filenames, directory-structure

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Combine paths in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412380/combine-paths-in-java)

Perl has a module called [`File::Spec`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3A%3ASpec) that has a `catfile()` method:

```
$x = File::Spec->catfile('a', 'b', 'c');
```

This module returns different results depending on the operating system. The above call gives a file path that on Linux would be `/a/b/c`, on classic Mac OS would be `:a:b:c`, and on Windows would be (I believe) `a:\b\c` (or maybe `\a\b\c`). `File::Spec->catfile()` also handles consecutive directory separators, so if you pass in `'a/', '/b'` you'd get back `a/b`.

Is there anything that will do this in Java? I know there's the `File.separatorChar` and `File.separator` fields, but I'd really like to just use a method that takes an array of `String`s (or a variable number of `String`s) and returns a `String` for the full path.

Comment: A similar question, with good answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/711993/does-java-have-a-path-joining-method