# Appending to a Path Java us

Tags: java, path

Is there an easy way to append to a path created like this:

```
 final Path path = Files.createTempDirectory(...);
```

Suppose this creates a temp dir in /tmp/xyx_123/. Now I want path to create another folder under /tmp/xyz_123/ called foo something like

```
 path.createDirectory("foo"); or path.appendDirectory("foo");
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: [Path operations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/pathOps.html) might be a good place to start, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/711993/does-java-have-a-path-joining-method) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/412380/combine-paths-in-java) might also be useful

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
Path path = Files.createTempDirectory("xyx_123");
File fPath = path.toFile();
File addedDir = new File(fPath, "foo");
addedDir.mkdir();
```

Answer (score 1):

Straight from [Path Operations, Joing two paths](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/pathOps.html#resolve)

```
// Solaris
Path p1 = Paths.get("/home/joe/foo");
// Result is /home/joe/foo/bar
System.out.format("%s%n", p1.resolve("bar"));
```

or

```
// Microsoft Windows
Path p1 = Paths.get("C:\\home\\joe\\foo");
// Result is C:\home\joe\foo\bar
System.out.format("%s%n", p1.resolve("bar"));
```