# Unzip a zipped file on sd card in Android application

Tags: android, file, sd-card, unzip

I have a zipped password protected a video file saved on sd card on android emulator. Now i want to unzip that video file on sd card through code. How can i achieve that? Any help or code?
Thanks in advance

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=android+unzip+file

Comment: This question has been asked many times before. It's in the Java library rather than the Android one. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382996/how-to-unzip-files-programmatically-in-android

Comment: Have a look at ZipInputStream from the Android developer site: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html

Comment: Kotlin solution here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/50990872/1162784 It uses a File extension.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to unzip files programmatically in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382996/how-to-unzip-files-programmatically-in-android)

Comment: See this method: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76032406/12272687

Answer (score 23):

```
import android.util.Log; 
import java.io.File; 
import java.io.FileInputStream; 
import java.io.FileOutputStream; 
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry; 
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream; 

/** 
 * 
 * @author jon 
 */ 
public class Decompress { 
  private String _zipFile; 
  private String _location; 

  public Decompress(String zipFile, String location) { 
    _zipFile = zipFile; 
    _location = location; 

    _dirChecker(""); 
  } 

  public void unzip() { 
    try  { 
      FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(_zipFile); 
      ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(fin); 
      ZipEntry ze = null; 
      while ((ze = zin.getNextEntry()) != null) { 
        Log.v("Decompress", "Unzipping " + ze.getName()); 

        if(ze.isDirectory()) { 
          _dirChecker(ze.getName()); 
        } else { 
          FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(_location + ze.getName()); 
          for (int c = zin.read(); c != -1; c = zin.read()) { 
            fout.write(c); 
          } 

          zin.closeEntry(); 
          fout.close(); 
        } 

      } 
      zin.close(); 
    } catch(Exception e) { 
      Log.e("Decompress", "unzip", e); 
    } 

  } 

  private void _dirChecker(String dir) { 
    File f = new File(_location + dir); 

    if(!f.isDirectory()) { 
      f.mkdirs(); 
    } 
  } 
}
```

In your case::

```
String zipFilename = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/files.zip"; 
String unzipLocation = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/unzipped/"; 

Decompress d = new Decompress(zipFilename, unzipLocation); 
d.unzip();
```

Comment: Divyesh Thanks for reply. But still i m confused because my zipped file is password protected so how i will match that password to enter in the file?

Comment: Just a complement to your answer, the actual entry read and file writing could be done in chunks for much higher performance instead of byte by byte: `byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];        for (int c = zin.read(buffer); c != -1; c = zin.read(buffer)) { 
            fout.write(buffer, 0, c); 
          }`

Comment: @nobre do you think same code works for unzipping or unpacking the expansion APK Expansion Files obb files?

Comment: Here is a Xamarin.Android version: https://gist.github.com/pauldendulk/18958a610adb50990d96

Answer (score 5):

To unpacking the password protected file use this library:

http://www.lingala.net/zip4j/download.php

it is so easy.

```
ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(YourZipFile);
if(zipFile.isEncrypted())
    zipFile.setPassword(Password);
zipFile.extractAll(Destination);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is slightly more cleaner version of Samir's code with using Apache's `IOUtils.copy()` for copying files and `finally` block. If you have large files in archive then better use `IOUtils.copyLarge()`.

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;

public class ZipUtils {
    public static void unzip(InputStream is, File path) {
        checkDir(path);
        ZipInputStream zis = null;
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            zis = new ZipInputStream(is);
            ZipEntry ze;
            while ((ze = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                File entryFile = new File(path, ze.getName());
                if (ze.isDirectory()) {
                    checkDir(entryFile);
                } else {
                    fos = new FileOutputStream(entryFile);
                    IOUtils.copy(zis, fos);
                    fos.close();
                    fos = null;
                }
                zis.closeEntry();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (zis != null) {
                try {
                    zis.close();
                } catch (IOException ignore) {
                }
            }
            if (fos != null) {
                try {
                    fos.close();
                } catch (IOException ignore) {
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void checkDir(File path) {
        if (!path.exists()) {
            path.mkdirs();
        } else if (!path.isDirectory()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Path is not directory");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Other answers not really work on sdcard(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() != SDCARD) in kitkat and above.
but you can use this code for api 21 and above! for more help to get zipDocumentFile read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26744842/how-to-use-the-new-sd-card-access-api-presented-for-android-5-0-lollipop/26765884#26765884) :

```
/**
 * @return true->successful
 */
public static Boolean unzip(Context context, DocumentFile zipDocumentFile) {

    try {

        InputStream inputStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(zipDocumentFile.getUri());
        assert inputStream != null;
        ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(inputStream, BUFFER_SIZE));

        ZipEntry ze;
        while ((ze = zipInputStream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            if (ze.isDirectory()) {

                String[] paths = ze.getName().split("/");

                DocumentFile documentFile = null;
                for (String path : paths) {
                    if (documentFile == null) {
                        documentFile = zipDocumentFile.getParentFile().findFile(path);
                        if (documentFile == null)
                            documentFile = zipDocumentFile.getParentFile().createDirectory(path);
                    } else {
                        DocumentFile newDocumentFile = documentFile.findFile(path);
                        if (newDocumentFile == null) {
                            documentFile = documentFile.createDirectory(path);
                        } else {
                            documentFile = newDocumentFile;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (documentFile == null || !documentFile.exists())
                    return false;

            } else {

                String[] paths = ze.getName().split("/");

                //Make Folders
                DocumentFile documentFile = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < paths.length - 1; i++) {
                    if (documentFile == null) {
                        documentFile = zipDocumentFile.getParentFile().findFile(paths[i]);
                        if (documentFile == null)
                            documentFile = zipDocumentFile.getParentFile().createDirectory(paths[i]);
                    } else {
                        DocumentFile newDocumentFile = documentFile.findFile(paths[i]);
                        if (newDocumentFile == null) {
                            documentFile = documentFile.createDirectory(paths[i]);
                        } else {
                            documentFile = newDocumentFile;
                        }
                    }
                }

                DocumentFile unzipDocumentFile;
                if (documentFile == null) {
                    unzipDocumentFile = zipDocumentFile.getParentFile().createFile(URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(ze.getName()), paths[paths.length - 1]);
                } else {
                    unzipDocumentFile = documentFile.createFile(URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(ze.getName()), paths[paths.length - 1]);

                }


                // unzip the file
                OutputStream outputStream = context.getContentResolver().openOutputStream(unzipDocumentFile.getUri());

                int read;
                byte[] data = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
                assert outputStream != null;
                while ((read = zipInputStream.read(data, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)) != -1)
                    outputStream.write(data, 0, read);

                zipInputStream.closeEntry();

            }
        }

        return true;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }

}
```