# How to update ProgressBar for UnZip File in Android

Tags: java, android, progress-bar, unzip

how can I use a determinate progressbar during the unzip process in a Android Application?

I know what I need to file has been processed to update the progressbar, but do not know how to derive this information.

Thank you!

**P.S.** I use to unzip the code found in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7697493/1364296

Comment: Which "unzip code" are you actually using? Please include it in your question.

Comment: The code is that included in this post:http://stackoverflow.com/a/7697493/1364296

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how can I use a determinate progressbar during the unzip process in a Android Application?

Use [`ZipFile`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html) to find the number of entries. Use that with `setMax()` on your `ProgressBar` to set the upper progress bound. Then, as you process each file, increment the progress by 1.

Comment: Nice and Easy, I dont know why others found it very tricky or difficult..Thanks for the direct clue. to use `ZipFile.size()`

Answer (score 1):

for the zip code use this .

```
public static void zip(String[] files, String zipFile) throws IOException {
    BufferedInputStream origin = null;
    ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(zipFile)));
    try { 
        byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(files[i]);    
            origin = new BufferedInputStream(fi, BUFFER_SIZE);
            try {
                ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(files[i].substring(files[i].lastIndexOf("/") + 1));
                out.putNextEntry(entry);
                int count;
                while ((count = origin.read(data, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)) != -1) {
                    out.write(data, 0, count);
                }
            }
            finally {
                origin.close();
            }
        }
    }
    finally {
        out.close();
    }
}
```

try to use buffer when zip on unzip because it will be much faster