# Android expansion file

Tags: android, zip, apk, unzip, apk-expansion-files

I am trying to do an application which contain ~80mo of PNG (It's an offline app so I have to store them on the phone).

The application works perfectly in local but I can't upload an apk > 50mo. So I am trying to implement an expansion file which will contain all my PNGs. So I use this simple command on Linux: `_zip_ -0 _main.1.com.ctai.irisst.zip_ *_.png_` on my /res/drawable-mdpi to create my expansion file and then put it manually to `/Android/data/com.ctai.irisst/`
Then, I use [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7697466/unzip-a-zipped-file-on-sd-card-in-android-application) to unzip all my data on the storage of the phone, but when I start the app, I only get a blank screen for like 10s, and then Android tells me that the application is not responsive. I can see in a file explorer that ~10 PNG images are unzipped and in the `Logcat` that 1 file is extracted every second. (and if I use a buffer, it still take >20s to load my application)

I have implemented the following library :

```
"downloader_library","licencing_library","Sample_downloader" and "zip_file"
```

but I didn't really used it for the moment. (should I ? How ?)

My question is simple, how can I simply create an expansion file and use my images without interfering with the user experience ? I have not found so many tutorials on Expansion Files, and no sample projects, so I'm a bit lost.

Comment: You can add expansion files in Google Play store (If that's why you can't have your apk > 50m) also you can add a download screen that will be launched the first time the app is opened and there you can unzip/download/change/get or whatever you want, your images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to unzip your package. You can read all your PNGs within Expansion ZIP file with this:

```
// Get a ZipResourceFile representing a merger of both the main and patch files
ZipResourceFile expansionFile = APKExpansionSupport.getAPKExpansionZipFile(appContext,
        mainVersion, patchVersion);

// Get an input stream for a known file inside the expansion file ZIPs
InputStream fileStream = expansionFile.getInputStream(pathToFileInsideZip);
```

****EDIT****

Notice that in the code above, **InputStream** will point to the **file inside** your ZIP archive and not the ZIP file itself. For example, if you placed *flower.png* under a directory called *background* inside your ZIP archive, you can have an InputStream to that file as follows:

```
InputStream fileStream = expansionFile.getInputStream("background/flower.png");
```

****EDIT****

I think the location in which you placed your ZIP file is incorrect. According to Developer's Guide:

> If your package name is com.example.android, you need to create the
>   directory Android/obb/com.example.android/ on the shared storage
>   space.

After successful testing, you can upload your Expansion ZIP along with your APK through Developer's Console.

Have you read through the [APK Expansion Files](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html)? It's pretty straightforward.

Comment: Yes I've tried to read the Developer's Guide, but as a beginner I've been pretty quickly lost... If I use the function to read the Zip file as you tell me, will they be kept in memory ? It could be usefull to use them in a layout file, otherwise I would have to declare it in the Activity.

Comment: Are you gonna use them for UI or , for example, populate them in a grid such as thumbnail?

Comment: If you're gonna use them as UI (let's say Button Background), you have to do it programmatically. Just read the specific file and create a drawable from it and set it to your View on onCreate().

Comment: So, for exemple, if I have a list of images that I want to display, I use: int[] a = {R.drawable.xxx, R.drawable.xxy); if I want to use the zip ressource file to replace them, I should use fileStream.read() ?

Comment: Yes. But you have to create a Drawable from that file. Take a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html). There is a createFromStream() function which can be used to create drawable from InputStream.

Comment: Additionally, you can store your drwabales in an Array or Vector or any container and then use them for your logic. Drawable[] drawableArray = new Drawable[sizeOfArrayInt];

Comment: To be honnest, I don't really understand how to use this. I use :  ZipResourceFile expansionFile = new ZipResourceFile("mypath"); InputStream fileStream = ExpansionFile.getInputStream("/myexpansionfile.zip"); Drawer.createFromStream(fileStream,"src"); but I could not use it to replace a "R.dawable.xxx" (sorry for my absolute begginer level ... it's a shame)

Comment: I'm a junior noob either. So don't worry about that. Regarding your question, I will update my answer. Notice the edited part.

Comment: You can also test expansion files through the play store by using the alpha & beta options. See my post for some helpfull information regarding apk expansions and reading media directly from a zip.

Answer (score 1):

Some helfull information for people that end up here in this post since there are some things that changed in the way apk expansions work and also if you are using Android Studio to make the libraries work.

**NOTE 1**

You can't use draft anymore as the link to get the expansion file won't be active yet. You have to upload a version to Alpha or Beta first with expansion file. (adding an expansion file is only possible from the second apk you upload and up) So make sure you see the apk expansion file listed when you click the details in the developer publish section under APK.

**NOTE 2**

If you are using android studio and want to make use of the downloader library don't just copy the package name and java files into your own app src directory. Import the downloader library in eclipse and choose export => gradle build files. Afterwards you can import the library as a module in android studio.

**NOTE 3**

Not sure of this but I also think it's neccesary to download the app atleast once through the play store and have access to it with the account on your test device. So if you are working with alpha create a google+ test group and add yourself or other test devices to it.

**BTW**

With these libraries it's pretty easy to implement the apk expansion download just make sure:

1. your activity (the one where you want to implement the downloading
   of the expansion pack when the downloading has not been done
   automatically) implements IDownloaderClient.
2. you set up the service & receiver and set them up in your manifest.
3. The BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY in the service class is correct. Upload the
   first apk => look in Services and API's in the developer console
   under your app => License code for this app.

This code is used to see if the expansion file can be found on the device:

```
boolean expansionFilesDelivered() {
    for (XAPKFile xf : xAPKS) {
        String fileName = Helpers.getExpansionAPKFileName(this, xf.mIsMain, xf.mFileVersion);
        Log.i(TAG, "Expansion filename " +fileName);
        if (!Helpers.doesFileExist(this, fileName, xf.mFileSize, false))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

It uses the class XAPKS wich represents an expansion file, be it either a main or patch file, having a certain filesize(bytes) and associated with a apk version (the one it was first added in).

```
private static class XAPKFile {
        public final boolean mIsMain; // true
        public final int mFileVersion; //example 4
        public final long mFileSize; //example 126515695L
        // example => main expansion that was first introduced in apk version 4 and is 126515695 bytes in size

        XAPKFile(boolean isMain, int fileVersion, long fileSize) {
            mIsMain = isMain;
            mFileVersion = fileVersion;
            mFileSize = fileSize;
        }
    }
```

Its also quite easy to read movie files and other stuff directly from the expansion file using the zip tools that google has provided (com.android.vending.zipfile).

First get the expansionfile using the methods provided in the library, the paremeters are integers that represent your main expansion apk version (the apk version where the expansion pack you need was first added) and the patch apk version.

```
ZipResourceFile expansionFile = APKExpansionSupport.getAPKExpansionZipFile(context, APKX_MAIN_APK, APKX_PATCH_APK);
```

**Video**

For playing video directly from this zipresourcefile:

```
AssetFileDescriptor a = expansionFile.getAssetFileDescriptor(pathToFileInsideZip);
```

Now from this assetFileDescriptor you can get a FileDescriptor and use this in your mediaplayer, the correct syntax to get your mediaplayer to play the video also needs the second and third parameter.. Be it the startoffset and length you can get from the AssetFileDescriptor.

```
player.setDataSource(a.getFileDescriptor(), a.getStartOffset(), a.getLength());
```

**Other**

For all the other stuff (like images) you can just get an inputstream of the zipresourcefile:

```
expansionFile.getInputStream(pathToFileInsideZip);`
```

ALSO make sure you don't compress the videos in the zip for this to work!
for example not to compress .mp4 files:

```
zip -n .mp4 -r zipfile.zip . -x ".*" -x "*/.*"
```

Answer (score 0):

Even, if it is a zip file, it still needs to be stored in obb folder.