# Extract zip without errors

Tags: android, zip, extract, archive

How can i extract a zip file on android without getting a

"java.io.FileNotFoundException" error. I have tried 4 method and they all give me the same error. Does anyone know what the error might be?

This is the code that I am currently testing

```
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;

/**
 * This utility extracts files and directories of a standard zip file to
 * a destination directory.
 * @author www.codejava.net
 *
 */
public class UnzipUtility {
    /**
     * Size of the buffer to read/write data
 */
private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;
/**
 * Extracts a zip file specified by the zipFilePath to a directory specified by
 * destDirectory (will be created if does not exists)
 * @param zipFilePath
 * @param destDirectory
 * @throws IOException
 */
public void unzip(String zipFilePath, String destDirectory) throws IOException {
    File destDir = new File(destDirectory);
    if (!destDir.exists()) {
        destDir.mkdir();
    }
    ZipInputStream zipIn = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(zipFilePath));
    ZipEntry entry = zipIn.getNextEntry();
    // iterates over entries in the zip file
    while (entry != null) {
        String filePath = destDirectory + File.separator + entry.getName();
        if (!entry.isDirectory()) {
            // if the entry is a file, extracts it
            extractFile(zipIn, filePath);
        } else {
            // if the entry is a directory, make the directory
            File dir = new File(filePath);
            dir.mkdir();
        }
        zipIn.closeEntry();
        entry = zipIn.getNextEntry();
    }
    zipIn.close();
}
/**
 * Extracts a zip entry (file entry)
 * @param zipIn
 * @param filePath
 * @throws IOException
 */
private void extractFile(ZipInputStream zipIn, String filePath) throws IOException {
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filePath));
    byte[] bytesIn = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int read = 0;
    while ((read = zipIn.read(bytesIn)) != -1) {
        bos.write(bytesIn, 0, read);
    }
    bos.close();
}
}
```

Called by

```
try {
            unzipper.unzip(Location, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + 
   File.separator + "Extracted" + File.separator + Name + File.separator);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // some errors occurred
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: What does the `name` string contain?, and what is Location?

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7697466/unzip-a-zipped-file-on-sd-card-in-android-application

Comment: name is "file.zip" and locations is "/sdcard/file.zip"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7697466/unzip-a-zipped-file-on-sd-card-in-android-application also causes the same error