# Open a Zip File protected by password Phonegap Android

Tags: android, cordova, passwords, unzip

Ive tried many zip pluggin but none of them has a password parameter. Do you know any cordova plugin that can unzip a password portected .zip Format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The popular [cordova-plugin-zip](https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/cordova-plugin-zip) rely on `ZipInputStream` to unzip files, but this class do not support decrypting password-protected Zip files.

An alternative java decrypting library [called zip4j](http://www.lingala.net/zip4j/) exists, but isn't clear if it's compatible with Android. An [Android porting of zip4j](https://github.com/imasm/Android-Zip4j) is available, but [isn't present on maven repository](http://mvnrepository.com/search?q=Android-Zip4j) so you should add it manually to your project.

Moreover, seems that [somebody has written](http://blog.alutam.com/2009/10/31/reading-password-protected-zip-files-in-java/) his custom java class to decrypt zip files.

Following the source code of [the cordova zip plugin](https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/cordova-plugin-zip/blob/master/src/android/Zip.java) for Android, will be very easy for you to write your custom unzip plugin (and I hope that you'll publish it!).

*Edit*: see also [these interesting answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7697466/unzip-a-zipped-file-on-sd-card-in-android-application) to a similar question.

Comment: I ll try my best for developing my plugin based on your resources thank U.