# Package manager for android application

Tags: android, package

I am developing an android application that has different types of content (text, audio, images).

However, these contents are updated regularly in a server and must be updated to the android application.

There is already a webservice on the server that lets you check the last update of the contents.

I would like to know if there is a kind of  package manager for applications so that when the content is updated on the server generates an application package to be downloaded by the android application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of C2DM http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/

Comment: That solves the problem of the notifications. 
Is it possible to generate a zip file in the server side and the application unzip it?

Comment: Yes it is. From server side it depends on your application/web server. From client side you can use standard java libraries. Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382996/how-to-unzip-files-programmatically-in-android

Comment: As of November 2012 C2DM is deprecated. Use Google Cloud Messaging for Android instead: http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html