# How to get Properties file values in android?

Tags: android

I am new to android application development.

In my android project I place on properties file in assets folder.

My requirement is ,How to get the values from properties file?

please help me to go forward..

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10267594/how-to-access-assets-folder-in-my-android-app

Comment: what kind of property file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Properties.html.

Load the `Properties` from your file and then retrieve their values using the keys.