# Get values in Properties file with Android Library from Android Application

Tags: android

From this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10267594/how-to-access-assets-folder-in-my-android-app), I know how to obtain Properties within an Android Application.

However, if I want to write an Android Library, and intend to read a properties file (say `myconfig.properties`, how can I do so?

Given that the Android Library (e.g. it's called "myAndroidLib" ) has `android-support-v4.jar` , and this library is imported to an Android Application. Also given that `myconfig.properties` exists.

I found a piece of code in the Internet, but this works only within Android:

```
Resources resources = this.getResources();
AssetManager assetManager = resources.getAssets();

// Read from the /assets directory
try {
    InputStream inputStream = assetManager.open("microlog.properties");
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.load(inputStream);
    System.out.println("The properties are now loaded");
    System.out.println("properties: " + properties);
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("Failed to open microlog property file");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Since the page that you linked to does not have the word "properties" in it, are you sure that you linked to the correct page? Also, what makes you think that doing this from a library is any different than doing it in an application?

Comment: My library acts as 3rd party module that deploys to other applications. Main reason for this is to protect my source code and logic while I provide my logics to other applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I found a piece of code in the Internet, but this works only within Android

That code will work fine within an Android library project. You will need the hosting application to give you a `Context` from which you can eventually derive the `AssetManager`.