# Android: Unzipping files throws data errors or CRC errors

Tags: android, exception, zip

I'm working on a project that downloads a zip file and unzips locally. The issue I'm hitting is that the unzip process works like 5% of the time.

It's a mystery to me at this point because sometimes it works, but most of the time it throws data or crc errors. It'll even switch between erros even though the zip file hasn't changed.

I've tried zip files that were created by numerous tools wondering if the format was incorrect. But to no avail. Even zips created in the terminal don't work.

Here's my unzipping code:

```
try {
    String _location = model.getLocalPath();
    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(localFile);
    ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(fin);
    ZipEntry ze = null; 
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    while((ze = zin.getNextEntry()) != null) {
        if(_cancel) break; 

        System.out.println("unzipping " + ze.getName());

        if(ze.isDirectory()) {
            File f = new File(_location + ze.getName());
            f.mkdirs();
        } else { 

            FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(_location + ze.getName());
            for(int c = zin.read(buffer); c > 0; c = zin.read(buffer)) {
                fout.write(buffer,0,c);
            }
            zin.closeEntry();
            fout.close();
        }
    }
    zin.close();

    if(_cancel) {
        handler.post(dispatchCancel);
        return;
    }

} catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("UNZIP ERROR!");
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    System.out.println(e.toString());
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And here's how I typically create the zip file.

```
$>zip -r myzip.zip myzip/
```

Here are the two error outputs:

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: CRC mismatch
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.readAndVerifyDataDescriptor(ZipInputStream.java:209)
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.closeEntry(ZipInputStream.java:173)
    at com.XX.XX.XXIssueDownloader$7.run(XXIssueDownloader.java:222)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1020)

java.util.zip.ZipException: data error
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.read(ZipInputStream.java:336)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
    at com.XX.XX.XXIssueDownloader$7.run(XXIssueDownloader.java:219)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1020)
```

Anyone have any idea why I might get these errors? I'm not getting anywhere with these.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two things very important when loading Zip files.

1. Make sure you're using a request method that doesn't contain the Accept-Encoding: header. If it's in the request then the response is not a zip file, it's a gzip compressed zip file. So if you're writing that directly to disk while it's downloading then it won't actually be a zip file. You can use something like this to load the zip file:

   ```
   URL url = new URL(remoteFilePath);
   URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
   InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
   FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(localFile);

   //setup buffers and loop through data
   byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
   long total = 0;
   long fileLength = connection.getContentLength();
   int len1 = 0;
   while((len1 = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
           if(_cancel) break;
           total += len1;
           _Progress = (int) (total * 100 / fileLength);
           f.write(buffer,0,len1);
           handler.post(updateProgress);
   }
   f.close();
   in.close();
   ```
2. When using input and out streams, do NOT use the read(buffer) or write(buffer) method, you need to use read/write(buffer,0,len). Otherwise what you're writing or reading may end up with garbage data in it. The former (read(buffer)) will always read the entire buffer, but there may actually not be a full buffer, for example if the last iteration of the loop only read 512 bytes. So here's how you'd unzip the file:

   ```
   String _location = model.getLocalPath();
   FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(localFile);
   ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(fin);
   ZipEntry ze = null; 

   while((ze = zin.getNextEntry()) != null) {
           if(_cancel) break;  
           System.out.println("unzipping " + ze.getName());
           System.out.println("to: " + _location + ze.getName());
           if(ze.isDirectory()) {
                   File f = new File(_location + ze.getName());
                   f.mkdirs();
           } else { 
                   byte[] buffer2 = new byte[1024];
                   FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(_location + ze.getName());
                   for(int c = zin.read(buffer2); c > 0; c = zin.read(buffer2)) {
                           fout.write(buffer2,0,c);
                   }
                   zin.closeEntry();
                   fout.close();
           }
   }
   zin.close();
   ```

Comment: Great, I get `CRC error`,just because the downloading zip file is broken. I use `f.write(buffer,0,len1);` instead of `f.write(buffer)` in my code, then this issue resolved. Thanks.

Comment: I'm getting the crcError when I try to unzip an apk file on my Android device.

I'm guessing the code you guys are talking about is for Eclipse (or similar) on a PC. How can I avoid this error if I want to unzip the stuff off my Android device (Samsung Galaxy Note 2 with Android 4.1.2)?

Thanks! :)

Comment: @wodong - I was already using f.write(buffer,0,len1); in my answered code example

Comment: @VanyaBurduk - make sure you inspect my answer code thoroughly. make sure there are no issues with wrong lengths being read or written.

Comment: Thank you. Indeed, the fact that I changed the `f.write(buffer);` to `f.write(buffer,0,len1);` made all the difference. Allowed to stop having the CRC Check Error.