# Create files from zip - android

Tags: java, android

I have a folder `/mnt/sdcard/Bluetooth` which contains several `zip` files. Each of this zip-files contains only one file. How can I extract the content for each of these zip-files into a new file, containing the content of each zip-file? This is what I've done so far:

```
public class Main extends Activity {

Object[] arrayOfRarFiles;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    String path = "/mnt/sdcard/Bluetooth";
    String nameOfFiles;
    File folder = new File(path);
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
        if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
            nameOfFiles = listOfFiles[i].getName();

            if (nameOfFiles.endsWith(".zip")
                    || nameOfFiles.endsWith(".ZIP")) {

                try {
                    extractFile(nameOfFiles);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    Log.e("EXTRACTFILE SAYS: ", e.getMessage());
                }

            }
        }
    }
}

public void extractFile(String path) throws FileNotFoundException {

    String zipFileName = "/mnt/sdcard/Bluetooth/" + path;
    String extractedFileName = getApplicationContext().getFilesDir()
            .getPath().toString()
            + "Finger.FIR";

    ZipInputStream inStream = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(
            zipFileName));
    OutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(extractedFileName);





    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), zipFileName,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

The last toast, in the `extractFile` method outputs the name of each zip-file. The file inside the zip-folders are `.FIR` files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the following function which I've found in another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382996/how-to-unzip-files-programmatically-in-android).

Pay attention to set your path and file name parameters correctly based on your need.

```
public void extractFile(String path) throws FileNotFoundException {

    String zipFileName = "/mnt/sdcard/Bluetooth/" + path;
    String extractedFileName = getApplicationContext().getFilesDir()
            .getPath().toString()
            + "Finger.FIR";

    ZipInputStream inStream = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(
            zipFileName));
    OutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(extractedFileName);

    unpackZip(path ,zipFileName)



    /*Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), zipFileName,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/

}

private boolean unpackZip(String path, String zipname)
{       
     InputStream is;
     ZipInputStream zis;
     try 
     {
         String filename;
         is = new FileInputStream(path + zipname);
         zis = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(is));          
         ZipEntry ze;
         byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
         int count;

         while ((ze = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) 
         {
             // zapis do souboru
             filename = ze.getName();
             FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(path + filename);

             // cteni zipu a zapis
             while ((count = zis.read(buffer)) != -1) 
             {
                 fout.write(buffer, 0, count);             
             }

             fout.close();               
             zis.closeEntry();
         }

         zis.close();
     } 
     catch(IOException e)
     {
         e.printStackTrace();
         return false;
     }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: This does work, but I cant find my extracted files anywhere using Astro File Manager. Where in the code should i put the path where the extracted files should be placed?

Comment: They should be in the same path where they are unzipped. Have you checked there as well?