# How to unzip file that that is not in UTF8 format in java

Tags: java

I have a file e.g. test.zip. If I use a ZIP-tool like winrar, it's easy to extract (unzip test.zip to test.csv). But test.csv is not in UTF8 format. My problem here is, when I use java to unzip it, it can't read this file.

```
ZipFile zf = new ZipFile("C:/test.zip");
```

The thrown exception says that there occurs an error by opening that file.

On java http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/compression/ is nothing written about data formatting. Maybe the whole API is designed only for UTF8-format data. So, if I have to unzip data except UTF8 format, how to unzip it? Especially the japanese and chinese characters that holds more space size (except UTF8). I also found an API at 
http://truezip.java.net/6/tutorial.html where this problem is mentioned. But, I didn't get a way on how to solve it. Is there any simple way to solve this problem? Especially from the API that is passed from JAVA specification request.

Comment: What kind of "error in opening file"?

Comment: Describe the error you are seeing. Also try opening the file with Winzip, instead of WinRar. Your zip file probably is not in the zip format in the first place. This has nothing to do with UTF-8.

Answer (score 5):

JDK6 has a bug in java.util.zip implementation it cannot handle non-USASCII characters. I use Apache Commons commons-compress-1.0.jar library to fix it. JDK7 has fixed java.util.zip implementation.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html

```
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.ArchiveEntry;
import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.*;

public static int unzip(File inputZip, File outputFolder) throws IOException {
    int count=0;
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    ZipArchiveInputStream zis = null;
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
        fis = new FileInputStream(inputZip);
        zis = new ZipArchiveInputStream(fis, "Cp1252", true); // this supports non-USACII names
        ArchiveEntry entry;
        while ((entry = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            File file = new File(outputFolder, entry.getName());
            if (entry.isDirectory()) {
                file.mkdirs();
            } else {
                count++;
                file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
                fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                int read;
                while ((read = zis.read(buffer,0,buffer.length)) != -1)
                    fos.write(buffer,0,read);
                fos.close();
                fos=null;
            }
        }
    } finally {
        try { zis.close(); } catch (Exception e) { }
        try { fis.close(); } catch (Exception e) { }
        try { if (fos!=null) fos.close(); } catch (Exception e) { }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No, zip files are *not* just for UTF-8 data. Zip files don't try to interpret the data within the files at all, and neither does the Java API.

There may be issues around non-ASCII *names* of files, but the file contents themselves shouldn't be a problem at all. In your case, it looks like the name of the file is just `test.zip`, so you shouldn't be running into any name encoding issues.

If the file can't be *opened*, then it sounds like you've got a different problem. Are you sure the file exists where you expect it to be?

Comment: When i am unziping the file that is in UTF 8 ,the code is working.But,when the file to unzip is not in utf8 format in code
 ZipInputStream zis = 
            new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(zipFile));
        ZipEntry ze = zis.getNextEntry(); ze is null.

Comment: @abishkar: That sounds very unlikely to me. Please show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 1):

can you try below code? For more examples check here http://java2novice.com/java-collections-and-util/zip/unzip/

```
FileInputStream fis = null;
    ZipInputStream zipIs = null;
    ZipEntry zEntry = null;
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(filePath);
        zipIs = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(fis));
        while((zEntry = zipIs.getNextEntry()) != null){
            try{
                byte[] tmp = new byte[4*1024];
                FileOutputStream fos = null;
                String opFilePath = "C:/"+zEntry.getName();
                System.out.println("Extracting file to "+opFilePath);
                fos = new FileOutputStream(opFilePath);
                int size = 0;
                while((size = zipIs.read(tmp)) != -1){
                    fos.write(tmp, 0 , size);
                }
                fos.flush();
                fos.close();
            } catch(Exception ex){

            }
        }
        zipIs.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As i remember this only happen when the file name is not encoded in UTF8.

If 3rd Component is not forbidden,try Apache Zip API.

import org.apache.tools.zip.ZipEntry;
import org.apache.tools.zip.ZipFile;

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code whic i used to extract all the zip files

```
try
    {

        final ZipFile zf = new ZipFile("C:/Documents and Settings/satheesh/Desktop/POTL.Zip");

        final Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = zf.entries();
        ZipInputStream zipInput = null;

        while (entries.hasMoreElements())
        {
            final ZipEntry zipEntry=entries.nextElement();
            final String fileName = zipEntry.getName();
        // zipInput = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName));
            InputStream inputs=zf.getInputStream(zipEntry);
            //  final RandomAccessFile br = new RandomAccessFile(fileName, "r");
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputs, "UTF-8"));
                FileWriter fr=new FileWriter(f2);
            BufferedWriter wr=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f2) );

            while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                wr.write(line);
                System.out.println(line);
                wr.newLine();
                wr.flush();
            }
            br.close();
            zipInput.closeEntry();
        }


    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.print(e);
    }
    finally
    {
        System.out.println("\n\n\nThe had been extracted successfully");

    }
```

This code really works me in a good manner.