# Char set issue in ZipEntry.getName()

Tags: java, unzip

in my project, i have a functionality of uploading zip.

when user upload any zip, my system extract that file and display the folder structure to user.

if zip file contain the file have name like Õ.txt then it will bi Display like O.txt.

```
ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(filePath, Charset.forName("UTF8"));
Enumeration entries = zipFile.entries();
while(entries.hasMoreElements())
{

ZipEntry entry = (ZipEntry)entries.nextElement();
System.out.println(entry.getName());

}
```

above is my code to read zip entry.

now, when i try to get the Name of entry, it will give me O.txt instead of Õ.txt.

i have test this code with JDK 7 but having the same result.

i have also tried the different encoding type like CP437, IBM437, ISO-8859-1 and ISO-8859-1 but no change in the result.

so pleas suggest me the way which can support all the character at the time of getting entry from the zip file

Thanks & Regards
Yatin

Comment: Yatin, I reckon that java reads that file name properly, but the console where you're seeing the output doesn't support unicode characters. If you debug the code, do you see the correct name?

Comment: Hi

yes, i have seen that thing through debugger as well.

thanks & regards
montu v boda

Comment: Have you tried Cp1252 encoding? It works with ApacheCommons-compress library which Im using in JDK6 http://stackoverflow.com/a/20523390/185565

Answer (score 0):

It seems there may be something wrong with your environment and not necessarily the way you access the ZIP file. Here's a check list:

- Does the ZIP file really contain a UTF-8 encoded entry with that name? Use a tool like 7-Zip to verify.
- Does the JVM use the correct character set? Check the system property file.encoding.
- Does the encoding of your output terminal / window match this setting?

After all, the result will only be correct if all elements of the processing chain use correct settings.

Comment: my question is how i can know the encoding of zip file?

if create the zip file using 7zip and upload that file in my system then it works fine...

can you suggest me what i have to do if zip file made through any tools?



thanks & regards

Comment: There are only two valid encodings for ZIP files: CP437 (standard by convention) and UTF-8 (standard by specification). What is used depends on the tool which created the ZIP file - not all do it correctly. 7-zip should work fine. Before JSE 7, Java did it wrong (always used UTF-8 but did not set the appropriate bit flag in the file). For details, see Appendix D of the ZIP File Format Specification at http://www.pkware.com/documents/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT