# encoding of filenames in Zip

Tags: java, file-upload, file-io, zip

In a program to import multiple attachments, user can zip all the required files and upload all of them in one go. Now the issue arises when one or more of these files having foreign characters in their name. To be clear, the issue is not with the zip file name, but with name of the file present inside the zip.

I found that “java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.getNextEntry” is calling “java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.readLOC” which in turn calling “java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.getUTF8String”.

I think the possible solutions are setting the JVM system property “zip.altEncoding” to required encoding, or creating the local copy of “java.util.zip.ZipInputStream” and modifying it.

Any help

Comment: The [Ant manual for the `<zip>` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/zip.html#encoding) has a very good discussion of the issues around filename encoding in the zip format.  The commons-compress [ZipArchiveInputStream](http://commons.apache.org/compress/apidocs/org/apache/commons/compress/archivers/zip/ZipArchiveInputStream.html) is an alternative to the `java.util.zip` classes that handles these issues rather better.

Comment: See this answer, its using ApacheCommons-compress jar fixing filename encoding issues. http://stackoverflow.com/a/20523390/185565