# epub 3 + android + parser + how to

Tags: android, xml-parsing, epub3

My next project is writting an Android application that would support reading EPUB version 3 files.

I wont be able to use any libraries (that would support this) since i need to write everything from scratch and i cant find any good "starting point" of how to read epub files, how to show them in webview and so on.

So are there  any tutorials or how to parse through this epub 3 format and show them in webview
in android.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I suggest breaking down the problem into smaller pieces that you can research individually:

- EPUB uses zip as its container, so you'll need a way to read zip files. If you can't use a library for this, then you could roll your own unzip code. ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382996/how-to-unzip-files-programmatically-in-android))
- Parsing EPUB. If you can't use a third-party library, then you'll need to read the source code for an EPUB library, learn the algorithm(s), and then implement them yourself. The format is based on XHTML, CSS, etc., and should be straightforward to display in a `WebView` once you understand the layout of the files.
- Display the output in a `WebView`. You can either point the `WebView` at a local file or pass the markup for a given page directly using `WebView.loadData()`.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Are there any tutorials or examples anywhere that i could use to see how to parse through and show(for epub3) ? Unzipping will not be a problem. Thank you

Comment: I would also like to know is there any example of how to parse this new epub 3 format table of contents, it seems now there is no more ncx file. Thanks