# Android Unzip zip file

Tags: java, android

I need some help really fast. I am having troubles with unzipping a file that I have downloaded to my phone as a background process in the app that I am building. The code that I have downloads a zip file from a server that I have set up specifically for the app. The zip file is not corrupted or anything like that. But if you guys could help me find a way to unzip the file that would be fantastic I have tried a few different ways and I cant seem to get it right. :/

Comment: Check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7420690/1817029

Comment: okay sweet thank you I will check it out

Comment: I tried to use this one but I'm not able to get it to work like it runs through the script but it is not creating another folder that has the contents of the zip file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use open source "zt-zip" to solve your problem:[zt-zip](https://github.com/zeroturnaround/zt-zip)

Answer (score 0):

I use zip4j at the moment - here an example usage: https://github.com/ligi/PassAndroid/blob/master/src/main/java/org/ligi/passandroid/ui/UnzipPassController.java#L66

Comment: Okay sweet how are you using it if I may ask?

Comment: to unzip the passes - see the linked code-lines - basically a 2liner to unzip