# How to unzip a folder on install

Tags: android, installation

We have a zip folder that contains sounds and pictures in our app.

When someone download the app, we want it to be installed on the tablet so the app can take the ressources it needs in the unzipped folder.

How can we do to put the zip on the tablet and unzip it ONLY on the installation?

We tried to look that thread : [How to unzip files programmatically in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382996/how-to-unzip-files-programmatically-in-android) but couldn't find a way to make it work for our case. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Why not just place those files (_sounds and picture_) in the `assets` folder instead? To extract the zip file, you would have to include / package the zip file in the `assets` folder anyway. I don't see a reason for the extra step.

Comment: You can embed zip file in assets folder when export apk then in the first time app run then you can extract it to other path (sdcard) to use.

Comment: we would like an external folder so the user can add ressources whenever he wants in it, but we've never done such a thing so we're kinda lost, that's why we thought the best way was to install a folder on the tablet. But we found no way to do that and there is not much help about how to do this on the Internet

Comment: @JohnnyBgud: Still, you could simply _bundle_ the audio and image files in the `assets` folder and use [this solution for example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4447477/450534), to transfer the files to a location on the sdcard. That way, your use case will be served. And it would be a much simpler method as compared to unzipping.

Comment: Okay so the easy way to do this is : put zip file in assets, unzip this on the desired path (using the same method as the linked thread) on the first time app runs and that's it?

Comment: @Iceman Thanks it looks like the easiest solution indeed, I'm sorry if I duplicate a question but I really had no idea on how to do so..; thanks for the advices

Comment: You are welcome @JohnnyBgud. I am glad I could point you to a solution ;-)

Comment: Just one last thingy, can the assets contain a folder? Our data is stocked this way : mainfolder -> multiple small folders -> one sound one image ineach folder. Can we just move the main folder or not? this is why we wanted to zip it at first (I don't know if i'm able to ask it here in the comments i'm quite new here as an asker)

Comment: Oh absolutely. I have often had 1 _root_ folder in the assets folder with 2 - 3 sub folders in the _root_ folder. And they work just fine. Just pay attention to the paths when coding and you'll be good to go.