# How to ZIP specific file programmatically

Tags: android, zip

How to zip specific file in android? for example I only want to zip random file in my phone storage like video.mp4, music.mp3, word.docx, image.jpeg. i tried to search the same question here and they always say that try this link [Zipping Files with Android (Programmatically)](http://jondev.net/articles/Zipping_Files_with_Android_(Programmatically)) but the page is already not found. do you have alternative link for this?

Thank you in advance! I appreciate it.

Comment: please take a look at this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/47154408/2101822

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [ZipOutputStream](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html)

You open a new FileOutputStream to write a file, followed by a ZipOutputStream to write a ZIP. Then you create ZipEntrys for every file you want to zip and write them. Don't forget to close the ZipEntrys and the streams.

For example:

```
// Define output stream
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("zipname.zip");
ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);

// alway use a try catch block and close the zip in the finally
try {
    ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry("entryname.txt");
    zos.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
    // write any content you like
    zos.write("file content".getBytes());
    zos.closeEntry();
}
catch (Exception e) {
    // unable to write zip
}
finally {
    zos.close();
}
```

Hope it helped!