# How to read kmz file of google map in android

Tags: android, google-maps, kmz

I have the KMZ file and I want to parse that KMZ file so that I can read the data of that file I tried to use `KmlLayer` but didn't get any help from it here is my code

```
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(path);
KmlLayer layer = new KmlLayer(mMap, inputStream, getApplicationContext());
layer.addLayerToMap();
```

but I got Parsing exception while I am creating the object of KmlLayer any solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because [KMZ](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmzarchives) is zipped [KML](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut) you should [unzip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382996/how-to-unzip-files-programmatically-in-android) `.kmz` file to `.kml` before reading data or use [`ZipInputStream`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream) instead of [`FileInputStream`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileInputStream) like in this `createLayerFromKmz()` method:

```
private KmlLayer createLayerFromKmz(String kmzFileName) {
    KmlLayer kmlLayer = null;

    InputStream inputStream;
    ZipInputStream zipInputStream;

    try {
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(kmzFileName);
        zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(inputStream));
        ZipEntry zipEntry;

        while ((zipEntry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            if (!zipEntry.isDirectory()) {
                String fileName = zipEntry.getName();
                if (fileName.endsWith(".kml")) {
                    kmlLayer = new KmlLayer(mGoogleMap, zipInputStream, getApplicationContext());
                }
            }

            zipInputStream.closeEntry();
        }

        zipInputStream.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return kmlLayer;
}
```

And you can use it e.g. this way:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mGoogleMap = googleMap;

    // path to your kmz file 
    String kmzFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/KMZ/markers.kmz";
    try {
        KmlLayer kmlLayer = createFromKmz(kmzFileName);
        kmlLayer.addLayerToMap();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

NB! `createLayerFromKmz()` works only on "flat" KMZ structure.