# Load Kml file from storage and show in map

Tags: android, google-maps, ftp, kml

The file Kml is downloaded using FTP with the apache library and saved on storage:

```
    File dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
    File downloaded = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath() + "/0001_0005.kml");
    OutputStream outputStream1 = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(downloaded));
    boolean success = ftp.retrieveFile("/0001_0005.kml", outputStream1);
    outputStream1.close();
```

How can I convert the File into type KmlLayer and show it in the map? I can show the file if is imported from raw package on resources with no problems.

```
    KmlLayer layer = new KmlLayer(mMap,R.raw.test,getContext());
    layer.addLayerToMap();
```

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53625721/6950238) question and answer: KML - is "unzipped" KMZ.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like that:

```
private KmlLayer createLayerFromFile(String kmlFileName) {
    KmlLayer kmlLayer = null;

    InputStream inputStream;

    try {
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(kmlFileName);
        kmlLayer = new KmlLayer(mGoogleMap, inputStream, getApplicationContext());
        inputStream.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return kmlLayer;
}
```

and use it this way:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mGoogleMap = googleMap;

    // path to your kml file 
    String kmlFileName = dir.getAbsolutePath() + "/0001_0005.kml";
    try {
        KmlLayer kmlLayer = createFromKml(kmlFileName);
        kmlLayer.addLayerToMap();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```