# Combine two strings to a single string representing a path

Tags: java

I want to combine the strings `"test/"` and `"/go"` as `"test/go"`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`FilenameUtils.normalize()`](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html#normalize%28java.lang.String%29) from [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/) does what you want.

example:

```
FilenameUtils.normalize("foo/" + "/bar");
```

returns the string `"foo/bar"`

Answer (score 11):

Using only [`java.io.File`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html) the easiest way is to do:

```
String combined_path = new File("test/", "/go").getPath();
```

Comment: +1 for this simple solution without extra library although it is limitated to two strings (which is sufficient for most cases and for the question)

Comment: @K. Claszen really? Where in the question are Files mentioned?

Comment: @Sean Patrick Floyd You are right. Sorry, my brain sometimes injects content into questions and I can't do anything against it. Taken the question 'as is' we have to go with Heiko Rupp solution. Everything else is overkill.

Comment: @K. Claszen but that assumes that we know the parameters in advance, which would make the whole situation unnecessary

Comment: Note that this solution does work even when the paths don't exist. The question topic is *Combine two strings in a single string representing a path*.

Answer (score 5):

As suggested by [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412380/combine-paths-in-java/412495#412495)

```
public static String combine (String path1, String path2)
{
    File file1 = new File(path1);
    File file2 = new File(file1, path2);
    return file2.getPath();
}
```

Comment: FilenameUtils would be a much better route IMO, but if you want to go this route, you're better of doing something like.  new File("/home", "//foobar").getPath().

Answer (score 4):

Append both the strings and replace `//` with `/` as below

```
"test//go".replace("//", "/")
```

Output: `test/go`

Answer (score 2):

```
String test =  "test/";
String go = "/go";
String result = test + go.substring(1);
```

Comment: +1 for answering the question 'as is' without any further estimations.

Answer (score 1):

Supposed this is a question related to file names, than take a look at [apache-commons-io](http://commons.apache.org/io/) and its [FilenameUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html) class

```
final String test = "test/";
final String go ="/go";
System.out.println(FilenameUtils.normalize(test + go));
```

output on windows:

```
test\go
```

The normalize method will do much more for you, e.g. change '/' to '\' on windows systems.

By the way congrat's to your reputation score by nearly just asking questions :-)

Comment: just *asking* questions is what you meant probably :-)

Comment: @Sean Patrick Floyd That's what I meant! Fixed!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) method that joins an `Iterable<String>` of items with a `char`, after trimming all instances of this character from beginning and end of the items:

```
public static String joinWithChar(final Iterable<String> items,
    final char joinChar){
    final CharMatcher joinCharMatcher = CharMatcher.is(joinChar);
    return Joiner.on('/').join(
        Iterables.transform(items, new Function<String, String>(){

            @Override
            public String apply(final String input){
                return joinCharMatcher.trimFrom(input);
            }
        }));
}
```

**Usage:**

```
System.out.println(joinWithChar(Arrays.asList("test/", "/go"), '/'));
```

**Output:**

> test/go

---

This solution

- is not restricted to file paths, but to any types of Strings
- will not replace any characters found inside the tokens, only trim them from the boundaries

Answer (score -2):

Even simpler:

```
"test/" + "." + "/go"
```