# Folder added in Android external storage, but was not showed correctly on computer via USB connection

Tags: android, usb, directory

I've created a folder in my program and use MediaScannerConnection to get it visible on Computer.
I did just the same as the answer to this question: [add a folder in android program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13507789/folder-added-in-android-not-visible-via-usb)

Now the problem is that, on the computer, the folder doesn't show as a folder, but as a blank file.
Does anyone knows why this happens and how to get the folder show in correct way?
Thanks.

Comment: What happens after you reboot device?

Comment: I've not reboot device yet, and I'm looking for a method that doesn't need rebooting.

Comment: Yes, but it will help figure out the issue, knowing that after reboot it's fine or not.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, and I tried to reboot both the computer and the cellphone, and the problem is still there.

Comment: So obviously the problem is I. How you make the folder, not in the sync. Are you using `mkdir`?

Comment: I have also tried mkdir(), and nothing changed :(

Comment: Problem solved.
I tried to use the answer of this question:[create another folder inside the original folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31157882/mediascannerconnectionscanfile-converts-directories-into-files-when-accessing-t)

Comment: Problem solved. I tried to use the answer of this question: [create a folder or a dummy file inside current folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31157882/mediascannerconnectionscanfile-converts-directories-into-files-when-accessing-t)