# Java String as Part if a Path

Tags: java, string, methods, path

I would like to have a directory path that is A/%Name%/B, where %Name% is a string I declared earlier, is there a Path.Combine like in C#?  Or what could I use?

Comment: So far, (since I am relatively new to Java) I have tried nothing.  I don't know where to start.

Comment: Take a look at this post.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/412380/combine-paths-in-java

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it correctly , you are trying to format a String.

You can use

```
String directoryName = "test";
String path = "A/%s/B";

String.format(path,directory);
```

or something like below based on your requirement

```
File f = new File(String.format(path,directory));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) constructor:

```
File combined = new File(new File("A", name), "B");
```

You could even write a convenience method to do that if you wanted:

```
public static File combine(String base, String... sections)
{
    File file = new File(base);
    for (String section : sections) {
        file = new File(file, section);
    }
    return file;
}
```

Then you can call it as:

```
File x = combine("A", name, "B");
```

Note that using the `File` constructor like this is generally considered preferable to *assuming* a directory separator of `/`, even though in practice that works on all platforms that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
String yourString = ...;
File theFile = new File("A/" + yourString + "/B");
```