# can't play video file using Uri in android

Tags: android, video, android-videoview

Hi i want to play a video file but after showing video it is showing error that can't play video file i am using Video view and path of video is

```
Uri uri=Uri.parse(Environment.getRootDirectory().getPath()+"/Phone storage/video.mp4");
```

Can some help me how to play video file that is store on my phone

Comment: Try out with the `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()`

Comment: can you tell me the OS version here is support media check http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Comment: Its also bad form to use actual path separators -- cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/412380/combine-paths-in-java/412495#412495

Comment: Uri uri=Uri.parse(Environment.getRootDirectory()+"/Phone storage/video.mp4");

Comment: what need to edit on it to play

Comment: @KishorJoshi Have you tried like `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()` ?

Comment: @KishorJoshi Check out my answer and try out.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Uri.fromFile` instead of `Uri.parse`

Comment: what to add if my video is on home>phone Storage>video.mp4 how to play this video?

Comment: You can still use Uri.fromFile

Comment: how can you guide me what to add in path suppose video is on Home>File manager>Phone Storage>Video.mp4 how to add this can you write syntax for me

Comment: Sounds to me like its the root of storage, like someone else mentioned just use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/video.mp4"`

Answer (score 1):

Create "raw" folder in "res", copy your video file to raw folder, in your code you should to do that :

```
String UrlPath = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/"
+ R.raw.your_video_name;
Uri video_uri = Uri.parse(UrlPath);
video.setVideoURI(video_uri);
video.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
video.requestFocus();
video.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out this way:

```
Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+"Phone storage"+File.separator+"video.mp4");
```