# How to download a file from the internet using Java

Tags: java, file, download

Hi I am trying to write some code in my program so I can grab a file from the internet but it seems that is not working. Can someone give me some advice please ? Here is my code. In this case I try to download an mp3 file from the last.fm website, my code runs perfectly fine but when I open my downloads directory the file is not there. Any idea ?

```
  public class download {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

     String fileName = "Death Grips - Get Got.mp3"; 
     URL link = new URL("http://www.last.fm/music/+free-music-downloads"); 

     InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(link.openStream());
     ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
     int n = 0;
     while (-1!=(n=in.read(buf)))
     {
        out.write(buf, 0, n);
     }
     out.close();
     in.close();
     byte[] response = out.toByteArray();

     FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
     fos.write(response);
     fos.close();


     System.out.println("Finished");

}
```

}

Comment: Why do you think it should be in your downloads directory?

Comment: I guess that is the default location for downloading a file ? or do I have to specify where the file is going to be stored ?

Comment: Ideally, you would specify a full path. If you don't, you get the behavior explained in Jonathan's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every executing program has a **current working directory**. Often times, it is the directory where the executable lives (if it was launched in a "normal" way).

Since you didn't specify a path (in `fileName`), the file will be saved with that name in the current working directory.

If you want the file to be saved in your downloads directory, specify the full path. E.g.

```
String fileName = "C:\\Users\\YOUR_USERNAME\\Downloads\\Death Grips - Get Got.mp3";
```

Note how I've [escaped the backslashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367322).  Also note that there are methods for [joining paths in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412380). There is a way to get the [current working directory in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871051).

Comment: Hi, thank you for your advice. How could I specify the directory that I want the file to be stored ? many thanks

Comment: Hmmm I just used your code in order to specify the directory and it throws me an error saying that the system cannot find the specified directory. Any advice ?

Comment: @user3449550 Is now username on windows Bob?

Comment: Yeah that was the problem, my bad I had to change it to my username Many thanks!