# Reading image using openCV with absolute path

Tags: java, opencv, path, absolute

I need some help. I'm using OpenCV library, but when I try to load a file from absolute path, it won't load. I don't know where the problem is, because when I try to load it from the project folder, it works. Here's the main part of the code I'm using:

```
try{
     System.loadLibrary( Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME );
     Mat source =  Imgcodecs.imread("D:/ImageSource/test1.jpg",Imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
     Mat destination = new Mat(source.rows(),source.cols(),source.type());
     System.out.println(source.width());
     source.convertTo(destination, -1, alpha, beta);
     Imgcodecs.imwrite("test1WithAlpha2Beta50.jpg", destination);
  }catch (Exception e) {
     System.out.println("error: " + e.getMessage());
  }
```

Comment: are you getting any error? eg: file not found exception etc.?

Comment: Since you're working on Windows, have you tried changing the path to - "D:\ImageSource\test1.jpg" or "D:\\ImageSource\\test1.jpg" ?

Comment: Hard coding the actual path is not a good idea.  Try building up your path with parts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/412380/combine-paths-in-java