# java.io.File.plus() is applicable for arguments types: (java.lang.String) value: [\] in Ready API

Tags: java, file, groovy, ready-api

I have following Groovy script where I'm trying to fetch the directory name and the file name:

```
File dir = new File("C://Users//avidCoder//Project")
log.info dir //Fetching the directory path
String fileName = "Demo_Data" + ".json"
log.info fileName //Fetching the file name

String fullpath = dir + "\\" + fileName
log.info fullpath //Fetching the full path gives error
```

However when I run it, I get the following exception:

> "java.io.File.plus() is applicable for arguments type"

Why does creating `fullpath` variable throws this exception?

Comment: it works properly. At least the code I can understand from your question.  You are just adding strings there.

Comment: Actually I am using Ready API tool. There it seems to be some problem

Comment: I am getting this error in Ready API - "groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.io.File.plus() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [\] Possible solutions: list(), list(java.io.FilenameFilter), split(groovy.lang.Closure), use([Ljava.lang.Object;), is(java.lang.Object), wait()"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use `+` operator, Groovy takes the left side part of the expression and tries to invoke method `.plus(parameter)` where `parameter` is the right side part of the expression. It means that expression

```
dir + "\\" + fileName
```

is an equivalent of:

```
(dir.plus("\\")).plus(filename)
```

`dir` variable in your example is `File`, so compiler tries to find a method like:

```
File.plus(String str)
```

and that method does not exist and you get:

```
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.io.File.plus() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [\]
```

#### Solution

If you want to build a string like `String fullpath = dir + "\\" + fileName` you will have to get a string representation of `dir` variable, e.g. `dir.path` returns a string that represents file's full path:

```
String fullpath = dir.path + "\\" + fileName
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Because `dir` is of type `File` and `File` has no `plus(String)` method.

You probably want

```
String fullpath = dir.path + "\\" + fileName
```

And in case you ever want to use it on other Platforms than Windows:

```
String fullpath = dir.path + File.separator + fileName
```

You could also have a look at `Path.join()` which is explained in [an other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412380/how-to-combine-paths-in-java)