# How to refer to a classpath XSD in xsi:schemaLocation?

Tags: xml

For example, I want instead of referring to an online XSD like this:

```
<persistence xmlns="…" xmlns:xsi="…"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
    http://www.oracle.com/…/persistence_2_1.xsd">  <!-- online -->
```

To refer to a classpath XSD like this:

```
<persistence xmlns="…" xmlns:xsi="…"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
    org/hibernate/jpa/persistence_2_1.xsd">   <!-- classpath -->
```

Comment: Use an XML Catalog. 

See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412798/how-to-load-xmlcatalog-from-classpath-resources-inside-a-jar-reliably

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no standardized way of doing this. Some products may support classpath URIs: `classpath:org/hibernate/jpa/persistence_2_1.xsd`. If your product doesn't, you can probably write a plugin (LSResourceResolver) that enables the capability.

Answer (score 3):

My team had problem that Spring Boot couldn't find schema for Spring profiled unit tests when `xsi:schemaLocation` was provided as
`classpath:xmlschemas/requiredSchema.xsd`

After hours of debugging the solution was to use relative path:

`/xmlschemas/requiredSchema.xsd`

(xmlschemas directory was in resources root)