# xi:include in xml file within jar file does not work in WildFly

Tags: java, xml, module, wildfly, xerces

Here's the scenario:

I bundled several `.xml` (somewhat of a configuration) files needed for my application to run in an `.jar` file. The jar file has the following structure:

```
settings-1.0.0.jar
˪ resources/
  ˪ 1.xml
  ˪ 2.xml
  ˪ 3.xml
˪ META-INF/
  ˪ MANIFEST.MF
```

`1.xml` has the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
    <!-- Include 2 -->
    <xi:include
        href="resource:resources/2.xml" />
    <!-- Include 3 -->
    <xi:include
        href="resource:resources/3.xml" />
    <!--
    <map>
    </map>
    -->
</document>
```

based on [this](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/91829) article. When trying to access these includes (after successfully deploying my application) I get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 5; columnNumber: 43; An 'include' failed, and no 'fallback' element was found.
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:245)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:298)
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:121)
    at org.zcore.dkp.backend.mapper.MappingParser.parse(MappingParser.java:60)
    ... 327 more
```

I tried(&error'd) all thinkable options. What's the right combination for `xi:include`'ing an `.xml` file in a `jar`-file installed as WildFly module?

*Edit*: Here's how the xmlfile is loaded:

```
private void loadBackendMapping() {
    try {
        BackendMappingParser parser = new BackendMappingParser();
        InputStream in = ResourceLoaderHelper.getResourceAsStream(BACKEND_MAPPING_RESOURCE);
        if (in == null) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException();
        }
        try {
            parser.parse(in);
        } finally {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                log.warn("Failed to close " + BACKEND_MAPPING_RESOURCE, e);
            }
        }
        backendMapping = parser.getMapping();
        if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            log.debug(BACKEND_MAPPING_RESOURCE + " successfully loaded!");
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        log.warn("\"" + BACKEND_MAPPING_RESOURCE + "\" not found!");
        backendMapping = new BackendMapping();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new CenterwareSystemException("Failed to parse " + BACKEND_MAPPING_RESOURCE, e);
    }
}
```

`BACKEND_MAPPING_RESOURCE` contains the filename (`1.xml`).

Comment: What is your use case? Is it really necessary to package your settings in a jar file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412798/how-to-load-xmlcatalog-from-classpath-resources-inside-a-jar-reliably
See if it helps

Comment: Can you show the code that you use for creating parser/mapper?

Comment: @ctomc Sorry, didn't notice your comment. :-/ Added how the `1.xml` is loaded programmatically.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your XML parser.

As per your exception it seems you use SAX.
Try this article:
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-tipentres/

The above document uses the **SAX API**'s `EntityResolver` interface for locating resources in an XML document.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the "resource:" prefix from your URLs, as this seems to be a JBoss specific protocol.

Also emit the "resource/" path, as 1.xml, 2.xml and 3.xml all reside in the same folder and you usually specify relative path (from 1 to 2 and from 1 to 3).

Try the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
    <!-- Include 2 -->
    <xi:include href="2.xml" />
    <!-- Include 3 -->
    <xi:include href="3.xml" />
    <!--
    <map>
    </map>
    -->
</document>
```

Comment: What is the "relative path" of a stream? Not all XML documents come from a real file system...

Comment: The relative path is e.g. "resource" in the file listing on top. If you manage to get 1.xml loaded, 2.xml and 3.xml must be adressed relative to 1.xml -> so without any folder (when following the structure given in the question)

Comment: The XML parser does not know this. It gets a `Document`, or a character stream, or some other source it can read characters from.

Comment: If you additionally fill in the "SystemID" and an "EntityResolver" it can figure out the location of relative resources automatically.