# PlayFramework 2.3.x: Access public folder using URL with Play and Scala

Tags: scala, playframework-2.3

I am uploading a videos and images using web-service and save the images in our application. When i save the files, the files are save on root of application folder. I want to access those images and videos with `localhost` url, like: I upload the file and save under `app-root/upload/image.jpg`. In my route mapping file, i declare routing as below:

```
GET     /uploads/                                   staticDir:/upload
```

As define in [Play Documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.5/routes). But still getting an compile time error: `Controller method call expected`. I want to access image like this `http://localhost:9999/uploads/image.jpg`

Comment: `GET     /uploads/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/uploads", file)`

Comment: No @SarveshKumarSingh this is not the way. From this, i got another compilation error. Please join chat root for disucssion. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11937335/serving-static-public-file-from-play-2-scala-controller

Answer (score 0):

Well... One way of doing this is by adding following routes,

```
GET   /uploads/*file        controllers.Assets.at(path="/uploads", file)
```

But, it will interfere with the reverse-routing of already existing route which is,

```
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

And then you will have to use your these two assets routes as - `@route.Assets.at("public", filename)` and `@route.Assets.at("uploads", filename)` which means all your templates which use you public assets route as - `@route.Assets.at(filename)` will have to be changed. Which can be a hassle in an existing big project.

You can avoid this by using following method,

Create another controller as,
    package controllers

```
object FileServer extends Controller {

  def serveUploadedFiles1 = controllers.Assets.at( dicrectoryPath, file, false )

  // Or... following is same as above

  def serveUploadedFiles2( file: String ) = Action.async {
    implicit request => {
      val dicrectoryPath = "/uploads"
      controllers.Assets.at( dicrectoryPath, file, false ).apply( request )
    }
  }

}
```

The above should have worked... but seems like play does a lot of meta-data checking on the requested "Assets" which somehow results in empty results for all `/uploads/filename` requests. I tried to look into the play-source code to check, but it seems like it may take sometime to figure it out.

So I think we can make do with following simpler method ( It can be refined further in so many ways.).

```
object FileServer extends Controller {

  import play.api.http.ContentTypes
  import play.api.libs.MimeTypes
  import play.api.libs.iteratee.Enumerator
  import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext

  def serveUploadedFiles(file: String) = Action { implicit request =>
    val fileResUri = "uploads/"+file
    val mimeType: String = MimeTypes.forFileName( fileResUri ).fold(ContentTypes.BINARY)(addCharsetIfNeeded)
    val serveFile = new java.io.File(fileResUri)
    if( serveFile.exists() ){
      val fileContent: Enumerator[Array[Byte]] = Enumerator.fromFile( serveFile )
      //Ok.sendFile(serveFile).as( mimeType )
      val response = Result(
        ResponseHeader(
          OK,
          Map(
            CONTENT_LENGTH -> serveFile.length.toString,
            CONTENT_TYPE -> mimeType
          )
        ),
        fileContent
      )
      response
    }
    else {
      NotFound
    }
  }

  def addCharsetIfNeeded(mimeType: String): String =
    if (MimeTypes.isText(mimeType)) s"$mimeType; charset=$defaultCharSet" else mimeType

  lazy val defaultCharSet = config(_.getString("default.charset")).getOrElse("utf-8")

  def config[T](lookup: Configuration => Option[T]): Option[T] = for {
    app <- Play.maybeApplication
    value <- lookup(app.configuration)
  } yield value

}
```

But this method will cause some troubles in case of packaged-build deployments.

Which means, using the Play's `Asset` thing would be wiser choice. So looking again, the `controllers.Assets.at` which is actually `controllers.Assets.assetAt` uses this method at one place,

```
def resource(name: String): Option[URL] = for {
  app <- Play.maybeApplication
  resource <- app.resource(name)
} yield resource
```

Which means, it tries to locate the resource in the directories which are part of application's `classpath` and our `uploads` folder sure is not one of them. So... we can make play's `Assets.at` thingy work by adding `uploads` to classpath.

But... thinking again... If I recall all folders in the classpath are supposed to be packaged in the package to be deployed in-case of packaged-build deployments. And uploaded things will be created by the users, which means they should not be a part of package. Which again means... we should not be trying to access our uploaded things using Play's `Assets.at` thingy.

So... I think we are better off using our own simpler rudimentary implementation of `serveUploadedFiles`.

Now add a route in route file as,

```
GET         /uploads/*file                        controllers.FileServer.serveUploadedFiles( file:String )
```

Also... Keep in mind that you should not be thinking of using play to serve your uploaded assets. Please use nginx or something similar.

Comment: i got the following browser error when access the images from URL `The image http://localhost:9999/uploads/test.jpg cannot be displayed because it contains error`

Comment: @Sarvesh I had the exact same idea and tried the same thing, although it returns 404 when trying to load the resource. I tried copying the `uploads` directory at inside `target/web` and at root but it still didn't work.

Comment: Great efforts @SarveshKumarSingh, but with second code, my file is downloaded, not open in browser.

Comment: Yes... because we are still missing the `mime`-types for our files. Adding proper `mime` information will enable browser to understand the incoming file type and browser will try to figure out a way to handle it.

Comment: @HarmeetSinghTaara I have made the changes required to enable rendering of the files by browser ( given browser knows how to handle them, so png, jpeg, pdf's etc should render... others will be downloaded )

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh the, problem i thing we face is that, when we register image within routes like `@routes.Assets.at("assets/images/test.jpg")`. We easily get the image from URL, but without routes, we got an error.

Comment: Well... I did not understand yur last comment. But I think your `uploads` should be accessible now using both of following methods - `@controllers.routes.FileServer.serveUploadedFiles("filename")` in template and `localhost:9999/uploads/filename` in browser address bar.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh come to the chat room, we discuss , what i do. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73074/scala-and-play-framework-2-x-x