# How to enter a relative URL when linking to an access database

Tags: java, database, ms-access

I'm doing a Java project for school where we **have** to use MS Access to store the data.  I've managed to get the database up and running, however i can't seem to find how to make the link to the database relative.  I've searched the web and tried everything I can think of but nothing seems to work.  Anybody here that can help?

Here's how I've put the link now:

```
private static final String DATABASE_URL = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\\Users\\Badlapje\\Dropbox\\workspace\\FOOP\\Group62RISK\\Risk.accdb";
```

Which I then invoke as follows:

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL);
```

What I want to do is make the link relative, so all members of our team can use the same link.

Comment: What do you mean by *relative*?  If you want to share the DB place it on a shared drive (not local) and have all your team members reference this share.

Comment: @PM77-1 you can also post the database file as a local file inside a package in your project. I've posted an answer about retrieving the file path and converting it to Windows accepted path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the access database file location: `C:\\Users\\Badlapje\\Dropbox\\workspace\\FOOP\\Group62RISK\\Risk.accdb`. Just make sure to place this file in a folder that everyone has in its computer like `C:\\school-project\\Risk.accdb`.

Another solution could be to set your file inside your Java project inside a source package and then load the file absolute path using Java code (adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/573715/1065197)):

```
package edu.proj.res;

public class Main {
    public static String getDatabaseLocation() {
        return Main.class.getClassLoader().getResource("edu/proj/res/database.txt").toString();
    }
    public static String changeToWindowsPath(String path) {
    return path.replace("file:/", "").replaceAll("/", "\\\\");
}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(changeToWindowsPath(getDatabaseLocation()));
    }
}
```

Having a project structure:

```
ConsoleTests
- src
  - edu.proj.res
    + database.txt
    + Main.java
```

Program output:

```
C:\workspace\ConsoleTests\bin\edu\proj\res\database.txt
```