# loading keystore file, no alias found

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ssl, keystore, wildfly-8

I'm trying to use KeyStore in order to get info from a keystore. 
I've generated the keystore using this command:

`keytool -genkey -alias server -keyalg RSA -keystore server.keystore -validity 365` taken [this](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Examples) page.

Checking its info `keytool -list -v -keystore server.keystore` I get the following:

> Alias name: server
>   Creation date: Apr 30, 2014
>   Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
>   Certificate chain length: 1
>   Certificate[1]:
>   (other info here)

Using this command: `keytool -list -keystore server.keystore -alias server` I get this:

> server, Apr 30, 2014, PrivateKeyEntry,
>   Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): 28:65:5B:0C:B3:3C:C9:AA:F1:7C:CE:91:23:77:DD:0D:F8:54:70:B9

Now, my java code:

```
keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
keyStore.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream(KEYSTORE_FILE_PATH), "myPass".toCharArray());
keyStore.getCertificate("server").getPublicKey().getEncoded(); //here I get a null pointer exception - keystore.getCertificate("server") returns null.
```

Doing `keyStore.aliases()` returns an EmptyEnumeration.

The application uses maven, java ee 7 and I've copied the keystore file in the resources folder of my application. KEYSTORE_FILE_PATH has the value of "/server.keystore".

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Class.getResourceAsStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) returns `null` when there is no resource with the specified name.
[KeyStore.load()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html#load%28java.io.InputStream,%20char%5B%5D%29) resets the key store to the empty state when passed a `null` input stream.

It means that at runtime your code does not find the keystore resource and silently proceeds with the empty keystore.

- add a guarding condition that checks that `getResourceAsStream()` returned non-null value before passing it value into `KeyStore.load()`.
- review your code and building/packaging process in maven to ensure that keystore file is present at the proper location.

There are [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573679/open-resource-with-relative-path-in-java) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844307/how-to-read-text-file-from-relative-path-in-a-project) [about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608795/what-is-the-difference-between-class-getresource-and-classloader-getresource) `getResourceAsStream()` that can be of help for you.

Comment: getResourceAsStream did not return null. The project however uses multiple maven modules and the keystore was build into the respective jar and from what I got out of debugging the type being seen at runtime was ZipEntry. Moving the file to the module packaged as war did the trick. Thanks.