# Path can not be found, creates argument exception

Tags: java, netbeans

I know what the problem is I just do not know how to fix it. So I have an image that I am trying to render in my program. I use ImageIO to load the image. But it seems to have a problem wit the path I am giving it. I am using NetBeans as my IDE and I dont know if I am saving the image file correctly.

First method:

```
public void init(){
    BufferedImageLoader loader = new BufferedImageLoader();
    try{
        spriteSheet = loader.loadImage("/sprite_sheet.png");

    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    SpriteSheet ss = new SpriteSheet(spriteSheet);
    player = ss.grabImage(1,1,32,32);
}
```

the loader BufferedImageLoader class:

```
public class BufferedImageLoader {

    private BufferedImage image;

    public BufferedImage loadImage(String path) throws IOException{
        image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(path));
        return image;
    }

}
```

I have the image saved under a 'res' folder under 'src' folder.

Error:
`Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!`

Thank you.

Comment: where is your png file exist ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need to use getClass().getResource() ?

Most simple usage of ImageIO.read is as follows.

```
image = ImageIO.read(new File(path));
```

You may need to add folders to path also.

```
spriteSheet = loader.loadImage("/src/res/sprite_sheet.png");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using an absolute path for your file or if you need a relative check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573679/open-resource-with-relative-path-in-java) (eg assuming you have a res folder under default package did you try "/res/yourfile"