# How to specify the path for getResourceAsStream() method in java

Tags: java, inputstream

I know this question has been asked several times but I still can't get it work by those solutions.

I have a maven project. And one Config.java file located in `consumer/src/main/java`. Here's the content:

```
import java.util.Properties;

public class Config {
    Properties configFile;
    public Config() {
        configFile = new Properties();
        try {
            configFile.load(this.getClass().getClassLoader().
                    getResourceAsStream("property_table.config.txt"));
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String getProperty(String key) {
        String value = this.configFile.getProperty(key);
        return value;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Config config = new Config();
        System.out.println("URL: " + config.getProperty("URL"));
        System.out.println("PASSWORD: " + config.getProperty("PASSWORD"));
    }
}
```

I kept getting `nullpointer exception`. I know that's because it can't find the file `property_table.config.txt`.

At first I put the `property_table_config.txt` file in the same folder(`consumer/src/main/java/`) as Config.java file. And tried use `/property_table_config.txt` and 'property_table_config.txt`. Neither of them work.

And then I tried using absolute path, not working. And tried using `/main/java/property_table_config`, not working either.

Then I saw this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2103625/8159477.
So I make a directory called resources and put it under main folder (i.e. the path of the folder is `consumer/src/main/resources`, and create a sub-folder `config` under `resources`.  After putting the `property_table_config.txt` file there, I changed the code into this:

```
configFile.load(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/config/property_table.config.txt"));
```

But this still didn't work. Can anyone give some hint on this? Any suggestions will be appreciated!!

Comment: check your `target` folder, does your txt exist on it?

Comment: Can you try Config.class.getResourceAsStream("property_table.config.txt")

Comment: `getResourceAsStream` loads from your classpath.  The src directory has nothing to do with your classpath

Comment: @Jerry06 It's not directly under target. The path is target/classes/config/property_table_config.txt

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to `Class.getResourceAsStream`:

> This method delegates to this object's class loader. If this object was loaded by the bootstrap class loader, the method delegates to ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream.

> Before delegation, an absolute resource name is constructed from the given resource name using this algorithm:

> - If the name begins with a '/' ('\u002f'), then the absolute name of the resource is the portion of the name following the '/'.
> - Otherwise, the absolute name is of the following form:
>
>   `modified_package_name/name`
>
>   Where the modified_package_name is the package name of this object with '/' substituted for '.' ('\u002e').

This is how I understand the comments:

- If you use `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream`, send the absolute path from package root, but omitting the first `/`.
- If you use `Class.getResourceAsStream`, send either a path relative the the current `Class` object (and the method will take the package into account), or send the absolute path from package root, starting with a `/`.

But in addition to this, you need to be cognizant of your build system. With maven, resource files are stored under `src/main/resources`.

So, in your case, I believe making the following changes should resolve the issue:

- Put the file in `src/main/resources`.
- Change the code to

  ```
   this.getClass()
        .getResourceAsStream("/property_table.config.txt")
        //or `Config.class.getResource...
  ```
- Alternatively, use

  ```
    this.getClass().getClassLoader()
                    .getResourceAsStream("property_table.config.txt")`
  ```

I've tried this with a similar setup, and it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

`ClassLoader().getResourceAsStream()` is looking files only in classpath.
What you need is to have your config file in directory which is in classpath.

So, you have options:

- when you run your java application from command line you can set path to directory in -cp parameter or CLASSPATH system variable. point there is: directory from where you need to get config file must be in class path - not a file. (e.g. if file location is `c:\my_projects\test-project\config\my_config.properties` and `c:\my_projects\test-project\` is in classpath then `getResourceAsStream` call will be `ClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config/my_config.properties")`
- you can package your file into jar file and root of jar file is starting point for `getResourceAsStream("config/my_config.properties")`
- If your Maven project is a jar project you need to use Maven resource plugin to put additional resource(s) into jar.

BTW: Maven does not put anything into jar file from src/main/java/ directory (if you do not explicitly specify it for resource plugin)

If you use IDE like Eclipse with your Maven project src/main/resources is a part of build classpath. Double check is it there and if it is not - do "Update Maven Project" or add it manually.

Still ClassLoader will see your properties file from src/main/resources folder only when you run project in IDE not from standalone Jar file - if you did not package your file or provide location in classpath.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try following code.

> Config.class.getResourceAsStream("property_table.config.txt")

Update:
This is the code I tried.

```
package test;

import java.util.Properties;

public class Config
{
  Properties configFile;

  public Config()
  {
    configFile = new Properties();
    try
    {
      configFile.load(Config.class.getResourceAsStream("property_table.config.txt"));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public String getProperty(String key)
  {
    String value = this.configFile.getProperty(key);
    return value;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Config config = new Config();
    System.out.println("URL: " + config.getProperty("URL"));
    System.out.println("PASSWORD: " + config.getProperty("PASSWORD"));
  }
}
```

And I placed property_table.config.txt file withn test package and it worked.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
String dirBase = new ClassPathResource("property_table.config.txt").getURI().getPath().replace("property_table.config.txt", "");
```