# Absolute to Relative File Path in Java

Tags: java, relative-path, absolute-path

Given I have two `File` objects I can think of the following implementation:

```
public File convertToRelative(File home, File file) {
    final String homePath = home.getAbsolutePath();
    final String filePath = file.getAbsolutePath();

    // Only interested in converting file path that is a 
    // direct descendants of home path
    if (!filePath.beginsWith(homePath)) {
        return file;
    }

    return new File(filePath.substring(homePath.length()+1));
}
```

Is there some smarter way of converting an absolute file path to a relative file path?

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>
> [How to construct a relative path in java from two absolute paths or urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204784/how-to-construct-a-relative-path-in-java-from-two-absolute-paths-or-urls)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This question was asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204784/how-to-construct-a-relative-path-in-java-from-two-absolute-paths-or-urls)

Here is the answer just in case

```
String path = "/var/data/stuff/xyz.dat";
String base = "/var/data";
String relative = new File(base).toURI().relativize(new File(path).toURI()).getPath();
// relative == "stuff/xyz.dat"
```

Comment: All right. I'll close the question then and link to the other question.