# How to get the relative path name?

Tags: java

I am wondering how to get the relative path name? Any existing library can help this?

c:\123
 c:\123\1234\zaq\erf

I would like to get something like 123/1234/zaq/erf

Comment: you are saying that `c:\123 c:\123\1234\zaq\erf` will be passes as an argument and output is `123/1234/zaq/erf`?

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204784/how-to-construct-a-relative-path-in-java-from-two-absolute-paths-or-urls

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `relativize()` method in the `URI` class. Construct a URI from the base file path and then relativize your absolute file path.

```
String s = new File("c:\\123").toURI().relativize(new File("c:\\123\\1234\\zaq\\erf").toURI()).getPath();
```

Comment: Do not forget to escape the \'s with \

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Java 7, there is the [relativize method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#relativize%28java.nio.file.Path%29) of the Path class that does what you need.