# Java - shorten the path of a directory

Tags: java, file, path, directory

I would like to shorten the path of a directory.

I know the directory where the path must start, for example (the path starts from *1*):

instead of `C:\temp\top\1\file.txt`, I want to get `1\file.txt`.

Comment: use `File.separator` instead of backslash/slash, you can do something like `getParent() + getName() ` if you're using java.io.File

Comment: What's the question? What have you tried?

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204784/how-to-construct-a-relative-path-in-java-from-two-absolute-paths-or-urls)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Note: be careful with \ and /....*

You can traverse the path from file to root, to check if the dir is the dir you want:

```
File baseDir = new File(basePath);
File candidate = new File(fullPath);
String subPath = candidate.getName();
candidate = candidate.getParent();

while (candidate != null && !candidate.equals(baseDir))
{
    candidate = candidate.getParent();
    subPath = candidate.getName() + File.separatorChar + subPath;
}

// now if candidate == null the file is on another directory, you have to use all the path
// if candidate != null, then subpath has what you want
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try using method substring and indexOf from [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) object.

Example:

```
String path = "C:/temp/top/1/file.txt";
System.out.println(path.substring(path.indexOf("1")));
```

Comment: Maybe I get the question wrong. I think he/she wants to get the relative path from a full path given a custom folder.

Comment: Downvoted without further explanations...

Comment: I dind't say it was you ;) As I said I can be completely wrong with what the OP wants (I get what he says he wants though) but if I am mistaken and I deserve a downvote I would like to know why :)