# Java's File.toString or Path.toString with a specific path separator

Tags: java, file, scala, relative-path, path-separator

I am developing a Scala application on Windows, and I need to insert a path to a file into an HTML template. I use Java's `io` and `nio` to work with files and paths.

```
/* The paths actually come from the environment. */
val includesPath = Paths.get("foo\\inc")
val destinationPath = Paths.get("bar\\dest")

/* relativeIncludesPath.toString == "..\\foo\\inc", as expected */
val relativeIncludesPath = destinationPath.relativize(includesPath)
```

The problem is that the output of `relativeIncludesPath.toString` contains backslashes `\` as separators - because the application runs on Windows - but since the path is to be inserted into a HTML template, it must contain forward slashes `/` instead.

Since I couldn't find anything like `file/path.toStringUsingSeparator('/')` in the docs, I am currently helping myself with `relativeIncludesPath.toString.replace('\\', '/')`, which I find rather unappealing.

**Question:** Is there really no better way than using replace?

I also experimented with Java's `URI`, but it's `relativize` is [incomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/a/705963/491216).

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something. Why can't you relativize the path and then use `toURI()` instead of using `toString()`?

Comment: I tried that, but then I get an absolute URI which looks like this: ``file:/C:/root/dir/foo/inc/``.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `URI`. I didn't realize it could `resolve`, and it turns out that it is perfect for me.

Comment: Surprising that "Path" in java is so FIleSystem specific. Path could have been much more neutral and general purpose. And there is always "toFile" to move to FileSystem based operations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Windows implementation of the Path interface stores the path internally as a string (at least in the [OpenJDK implementation](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7-gate/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/windows/classes/sun/nio/fs/WindowsPath.java)) and simply returns that representation when *toString()* is called. This means that no computation is involved and there is no chance to "configure" any path separator.

For this reason, I conclude that your solution is the currently the best option to solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this issue. If you have a relative path, you can use the fact that `Path` is an `Iterable<Path>` of its elements, following an optional initial root element, and then can concatenate the pieces yourself with forward slashes. Unfortunately the root element can contain slashes, e.g. in Windows you get root elements like `c:\` and `\\foo\bar\` (for UNC paths), so it seems like no matter what you still have to replace with forward slashes. But you *could* do something like this...

```
static public String pathToPortableString(Path p)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;
    Path root = p.getRoot();
    if (root != null)
    {
        sb.append(root.toString().replace('\\','/'));
        /* root elements appear to contain their
         * own ending separator, so we don't set "first" to false
         */            
    }
    for (Path element : p)
    {
       if (first)
          first = false;
       else
          sb.append("/");
       sb.append(element.toString());
    }
    return sb.toString();        
}
```

and when I test it with this code:

```
static public void doit(String rawpath)
{
    File f = new File(rawpath);
    Path p = f.toPath();
    System.out.println("Path: "+p.toString());
    System.out.println("      "+pathToPortableString(p));
}

static public void main(String[] args) {
    doit("\\\\quux\\foo\\bar\\baz.pdf");
    doit("c:\\foo\\bar\\baz.pdf");
    doit("\\foo\\bar\\baz.pdf");
    doit("foo\\bar\\baz.pdf");
    doit("bar\\baz.pdf");
    doit("bar\\");
    doit("bar");
}
```

I get this:

```
Path: \\quux\foo\bar\baz.pdf
      //quux/foo/bar/baz.pdf
Path: c:\foo\bar\baz.pdf
      c:/foo/bar/baz.pdf
Path: \foo\bar\baz.pdf
      /foo/bar/baz.pdf
Path: foo\bar\baz.pdf
      foo/bar/baz.pdf
Path: bar\baz.pdf
      bar/baz.pdf
Path: bar
      bar
Path: bar
      bar
```

The textual substitution of backslash with forward slash is definitely easier, but I have no idea whether it would break some devious edge case. (Can there be backslashes in Unix paths?)

Answer (score 2):

Building on the `iterator` idea (my problem is similar: need the path for a web page, but it has to be relative and start with a slash)

```
StringBuilder foo = new StringBuilder();
relative.iterator().forEachRemaining(part -> foo.append("/").append(part));
```

`foo` will contain the appropriate path.

Answer (score -2):

You can fetch most of the system properties in Java. Take a look at this link:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html

You want this:

```
Key: "file.separator"
Meaning: Character that separates components of a file path. This is "/" on UNIX and "\" on Windows.

String sep = System.getProperty("path.separator");
```

Comment: I know that I can get the separator, and I can even set it globally if I am not mistaken. However, I am looking for a way to select a specific separator for a single operation or a single File/Path object.