# How to know the absolute path of folder in ubuntu

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, path

I made a java application in NetBeans on Windows which I need to deploy on Ubuntu. In my java application I have given the path where an excel file will get saved on the click of the button. My address  path is like this D://Excel. This is working fine in windows and file is getting saved at the given passed address. Now my problem is this i don't know how can I get the address path in ubuntu. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you hard-code the location (*which isn't a good idea*) or ask your user the location where the file would be saved?

Comment: keep all your files in Project folder that is what recommended.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

take your terminal and type

```
pwd
```

This will give your home folder path. Use that in your program.. It will be something like this /home/adarsh..

Comment: What if the file was not saved in `/home/adarsh` and some place else? Why do you think your solution would work?

Comment: thanx you sir for ur quick response..Sir how to get the path of 'excel' folder where i need to save the file

Comment: You should ideally pick up the location of the excel file from [Config](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/).

Comment: I think you have hard coded the locationn in your code. Create a directory in your home folder and save your excel file there. Please dont hard code the location. Its a bad practice

Answer (score 1):

The question seems like : [How to construct a relative path in Java from two absolute paths (or URLs)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204784/how-to-construct-a-relative-path-in-java-from-two-absolute-paths-or-urls)

Please refer above link. Hope this helps you.