# Construct a relative path in JavaScript from two absolute paths

Tags: javascript, path

Given two absolute paths, e.g.

```
/var/data/stuff/xyz.html
/var/data
```

How to create a relative path that uses the second path as its base? In the example above, the result would be: stuff/xyz.html

Another example:

```
/relative/sub/foo/sub/file
/relative/path
../../../path
```

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204784/how-to-construct-a-relative-path-in-java-from-two-absolute-paths-or-urls) but I'm looking for the optimal JavaScript solution instead of Java.

Comment: [use URI.js](http://medialize.github.com/URI.js/).

Comment: What do you mean by "optimal"? Optimal in code size, running time or memory usage?

Comment: code size. can't imagine memory usage or running time will be a considerable factor for something so trivial.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're running this on the server with node.js:

http://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_relative_from_to

This is their implementation:

https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/path.js#L233

This should work in the browser without really any changes. It's been battle-tested, so it already handles edge cases. It's not a one-liner, but it works flawlessly, which I think is more important. The POSIX version isn't bad, if that's the only think you need to support.

Comment: I'm running client side, but that looks workable. Will see if I can get it working.

Answer (score 1):

It's really easy to make mistakes with URL handling, so I highly recommend using a library to take care of all the nitty gritty details.

[URI.js](https://github.com/medialize/URI.js) makes this simple:

```
URI('/var/data/stuff/xyz.html').relativeTo('/var/data');
```

Comment: Looks like it would work but is there a more concise way than including a whole library?

Comment: Probably, but how close are you monitoring your performance to care?

Comment: @AdamJimenez, that's not an answer. You should be making your site work *first* and then testing with a performance optimizer to see where the greatest gains can be made in performance. Prematurely optimizing is only going to hold you back.

Comment: URI.js github page now recommends using JS URL API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL

Answer (score -1):

JS URL API should handle this within the browser now: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL

new URL(url, base)

```
// Base urls
let m = 'https://developer.mozilla.org';
let a = new URL("/", m);                                // => 'https://developer.mozilla.org/'
```