# How to get the relative file path difference in Java 7

Tags: java, path, nio, java-7

Hello everybody I have a problem to determine the difference between two paths.

Let's say there are two pathes `main.cache` and `another/system.cache`

I would like to get the folder difference between these two paths. For example for these two file it would be `another/`.

I do it because I have list of files (per line) in `another/system.cache` relative to the `system.cache` file.
For example

```
../images/a.jpg
../images/b.jpg
../images/c.jpg
```

I need to get the paths relative to the main.cache file so I would just join
`another/../images/a.jpg` (and then normalize it to `images/a.jpg`)

I was playing with `java.nio` and Pathes and trying to solve it with `relativize` or `resolve` but with no success.
For example `relativize` consider `main.cache` as folder and returns `../another/system.cache` which is nonsense.

Is there any simple solution I missed?
Thanks

Comment: -1 a path must not exists, name it folder or relative folder. main.chache is not a complete path and not a path to an existing folder, it is a relative-path or a folder-name or a file-name. another/system.cache is a relative-file or a relative-folder. Please change the question.

Comment: As I said: I tried relativize which consider file as a folder unfortunately, I tried playing with resolve which returns complete nonsenses for me. Also I found this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204784/how-to-construct-a-relative-path-in-java-from-two-absolute-paths-or-urls which will probably work, but my question is whether in Java 7 and NIO is not a more robust and modern solution.

Comment: @PeterRader I don't get what is wrong? They are all relative paths as written in the body of the question. Also the class in Java7 is called `java.nio.Path` which does almost what I need.