# function that gives the relative path in clojure?

Tags: clojure

I need a function that when given a base directory and another path, I've done a simplified version that just matches the absolute path but was hoping to also be able to intelligently deal with '..' and '.' in the path. I'm not sure what the best approach is

some examples:

```
(relative-path "example" "example/hello") => "hello"

(relative-path "example" "../example/hello") => "hello"

(relative-path "example" "/usr/local") => "../../../usr/local"
```

Comment: I'm finding it hard to follow your examples. Could you be more specific with your requirements?

Comment: try http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/pathOps.html#relativize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out after a bit of trial and error:

```
(require '[clojure.java.io :as io]
         '[clojure.string :as string])

(defn interpret-dots
  ([v] (interpret-dots v []))
  ([v output]
     (if-let [s (first v)]
       (condp = s
         "."  (recur (next v) output)
         ".." (recur (next v) (pop output))
         (recur (next v) (conj output s)))
       output)))

(defn drop-while-matching [u v]
  (cond (or (empty? u) (empty? v)) [u v]

        (= (first u) (first v))
        (recur (rest u) (rest v))

        :else [u v]))

(defn path-vector [path]
  (string/split (.getAbsolutePath (io/file path))
                (re-pattern (System/getProperty "file.separator"))))

(defn relative-path [root other]
  (let [[base rel] (drop-while-matching (interpret-dots (path-vector root))
                                        (interpret-dots (path-vector other)))]
    (if (and (empty? base) (empty? rel))
      "."
      (->> (-> (count base)
               (repeat "..")
               (concat rel))
           (string/join (System/getProperty "file.separator")))))
```

Usage:

```
(relative-path "example/repack.advance/resources"
           "example/repack.advance/resources/eueueeueu/oeuoeu")
;;=> "eueueeueu/oeuoeu"

(relative-path "example/repack.advance/resources"
           "/usr/local")
;;=> "../../../../../../../../usr/local"
```

Answer (score 0):

I adapted the [Java solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8555628/830988) to Clojure:

```clj
(defn relative-path
  [a b]
  (let [path-a (.toPath (io/file a))
        path-b (.toPath (io/file b))
        can-relativize? (if (.getRoot path-a)
                          (some? (.getRoot path-b))
                          (not (.getRoot path-b)))]
    (when can-relativize?
      (str (.relativize path-a path-b)))))
```

```clj
(relative-path "example" "example/hello") => "hello"
(relative-path "example" "../example/hello") => "../../example/hello"
(relative-path "example" "/usr/local") => nil
```

Note this only works if either both paths have a root or neither do since that's a limitation of [Path#relativize](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#relativize-java.nio.file.Path-).