# relative file path for writing file

Tags: java, file-io, path

```
I am trying to create a file using the following chunk of code

 String content = "This is the content to write into file";

        File file = new File("/Users/abc/output.txt");

        // if file doesnt exists, then create it
        if (!file.exists()) {
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        FileWriter fw;
        try {
            fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write(content);
            bw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Everything is working as expected, but I want to create the file in a folder relative to my current html page, any idea how I can do that? This way I am writing/creating a file which is outside my workspace.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you think you mean by _my current html page_?

Comment: A dot before the first slash: ./myfolder

Comment: I am making a service call from index.html (for example) which creates the txt file using the above code, now, I want the output.txt file to be in the same folder as my index.html page

Comment: @JudeM. I tried that and it did not work.

Comment: define `did not work`

Answer (score 0):

There is a URI library that you may solve your issue here.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html

This isn't my work but here's a similar post:

[How to construct a relative path in Java from two absolute paths (or URLs)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204784/how-to-construct-a-relative-path-in-java-from-two-absolute-paths-or-urls)

Maybe this would work for your situation?

String filePath = URI.relativize(new File("/Users/abc/output.txt").toURI()).getPath();