# How to write relative path

Tags: java, servlets, directory, relative-path

I'm having some issues writing a relative path.

I have a `servlet` trying to save an image under the web directory.

This is the servlet location:
`onlineShop/src/main/java/control/servlets/itemManagement`

And this is the directory where I want to save the image:
`onlineShop/web/UploadedPhotos`

What is the relative path to indicate (to the servlet) the directory in which to save the image?

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204784/how-to-construct-a-relative-path-in-java-from-two-absolute-paths-or-urls

Comment: Hhhm.. It's a good approach, but I was looking for a real relative path, don't know if it's possible. @SteveYonG

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
getClass().getResource("").getPath() + "fileName";
```