# Path.startsWith returns false for a Windows file path on Linux

Tags: java, linux, nio

Why would this be?

```
Path parent1 = Paths.get("/flugel/borf/noggin");
Path child1 = Paths.get("/flugel/borf/noggin/foo/bar/baz.jpg");
System.out.println("child1 startsWith parent1? " + child1.startsWith(parent1));
System.out.println(child1.getFileSystem());
System.out.println(parent1.getFileSystem());

Path parent2 = Paths.get("C:\\foo");
Path child2 = Paths.get("C:\\foo\\bar\\baz.jpg");
System.out.println("child2 startsWith parent2? " + child2.startsWith(parent2));
System.out.println(child2.getFileSystem());
System.out.println(parent2.getFileSystem());
```

returns

```
child1 startsWith parent1? true
sun.nio.fs.LinuxFileSystem@f5f2bb7
sun.nio.fs.LinuxFileSystem@f5f2bb7
child2 startsWith parent2? false
sun.nio.fs.LinuxFileSystem@f5f2bb7
sun.nio.fs.LinuxFileSystem@f5f2bb7
```

I'm running Java 8 on Ubuntu, but nothing about the javadocs for `Path.startsWith` explains why this occurs. Neither file path contains any actual files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check the code to see what is actually going on. So when you create a Path [normalizeAndCheck](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/sun/nio/fs/UnixPath.java#UnixPath.normalizeAndCheck%28java.lang.String%29) function is called. In your case this is called on `sun.nio.fs.UnixPath`. Since path delimiter for *nix  is `/`  path strings will be normalized by `/`.

In case of Windows paths there are no `/` so they will stay exactly the same, so it will compare  `"C:\\foo"` `"C:\\foo\\bar\\baz.jpg"` which are different strings and hence no common prefix.

Comment: I figured this sort of thing was happening, but it still feels surprising, somehow.

Comment: Thanks for the link to relevant source code, I tried to step through the wrong section, and thus didn't notice this. Good answer.

Comment: Great! Vote up for the answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think below line from Java Docs of [java.nio.file.Path](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#startsWith-java.nio.file.Path-) answers your question

> An object that may be used to locate a file in a file system. It will
>   typically represent a **system dependent file path**.

Comment: Hmm, I must have skim-read that bit, I focussed on the following sentence: "If the given path is associated with a different FileSystem to this path then false is returned." Which I felt meant my code would work fine.

Answer (score 0):

As described in the Javadocs, Java uses the "path separator" to determines the current operating environment path separator character. This can be accessed via:

```
System.getProperty("path.separator");
```

on UNIX based system it is "/", while on Windows systems it is "\". If you want to change these properties you can use the following to achieve that:

```
Properties p = System.getProperties();
p.put("path.separator", "\\");
System.setProperties(p);
```