# Java - create relative java.nio.Path from two java.nio.Path's

Tags: java, filepath

I have a `java.nio.Path` which points to an absolute path:

```
/home/user/project/resources/configuration.xml
```

I have a second `java.nio.Path` which points to the root directory of the project, also an absolute path:

```
/home/user/project
```

Is it now possible to create a `java.nio.Path` which holds the relative path between the two:

```
resources/configuration.xml
```

Comment: Similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204784/how-to-construct-a-relative-path-in-java-from-two-absolute-paths-or-urls

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is precisely what the [`relativize(Path)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#relativize-java.nio.file.Path-) method does:

```
Path confFile = Paths.get("/home/user/project/resources/configuration.xml");
Path rootDir  = Paths.get("/home/user/project");
Path relative = rootDir.relativize(confFile);
```