# How can I list all files and directories in <a> tags with a java web server?

Tags: java

I've been working on a basic web server from scratch using java. I was able to get most of the functionality working correctly. Right now, I am struggling with listing the default directory & files when you visit the localhost: by default. As in, I want to see a list of the directories and make their file paths clickable w/html a tags. How can I list all files and directories as a landing page for my java web server? The code that I wrote is below.

WebServer.java

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.Runtime;

class WebServer {

    private static String WEB_ROOT = "./";
    private static Socket socket;
    private static InputStream inputStream;
    private static OutputStream outputStream;
    private static DataOutputStream dataOutputStream;
    private static HTTPRequestParser httpRequestParser;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // Create Server Socket, listen on port passed in via Command Console
        // Use: java WebServer <port number>
        ServerSocket serverSocket;
        int port;
        if (args.length != 1) {
            System.err.println("Use: java WebServer <port number>");
            return;
        }

        port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
            System.out.println("Server listening on port " + port);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Unable to listen on port " + port + ": " + e.getMessage());
            return;
        }

        // Server listens for incoming requests
        while (true) {

            // Wait client to connect
            try {
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("Unable to accept connection: " + e.getMessage());
                continue;
            }

            System.out.println("Connection accepted.");

            try {
                inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
                outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
                dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(outputStream);
                handleRequests();

                socket.close();
                System.out.println("Connection closed\n");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("Unable to read/write: "  + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    private static void handleRequests() throws IOException {
        httpRequestParser = new HTTPRequestParser(inputStream);

        // GET or POST REQUEST ONLY
        String requestMethod = httpRequestParser.getRequestMethod();
        if (!(requestMethod.equals("GET") || requestMethod.equals("POST"))) {
            invalidRequestErr();
            return;
        }

        String fileName = httpRequestParser.getFileName();
        String filePath = WEB_ROOT + fileName;
        File file = new File(filePath);

        // File permission or not found error.
        if (!file.exists()) {
            fileNotFoundError(fileName);
            return;
        }

        if (!file.canRead()) {
            forbiddenAccessError(fileName);
            return;
        }

        // Assume everything is OK then.  Send back a reply.
        dataOutputStream.writeBytes("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n");

        String queryString = httpRequestParser.getQueryString();

        if (fileName.endsWith("pl")) {
            Process p;
            String env = "REQUEST_METHOD=" + requestMethod + " ";

            if (requestMethod.equals("POST")) {
                env += "CONTENT_TYPE=" + httpRequestParser.getContentType() + " " +
                        "CONTENT_LENGTH=" + Integer.toString(httpRequestParser.getContentLength()) + " ";
            } else {
                env += "QUERY_STRING=" + queryString + " ";
            }

            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/bin/env " + env +
                    "/usr/bin/perl " + filePath);

            if (requestMethod.equals("POST")) {
                // Pass form data into Perl process
                DataOutputStream o = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());
                o.writeBytes(httpRequestParser.getFormData() + "\r\n");
                o.close();
            }

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

            // Write response content
            String l;
            while ((l = br.readLine()) != null) {
                dataOutputStream.writeBytes(l + "\r\n");
            }
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes("\r\n");
        } else {
            staticFileRequests(filePath);
        }

        dataOutputStream.flush();
    }

    private static void staticFileRequests(String filePath) {
        try {
            if (filePath.endsWith(".html")) {
                dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-type: text/html\r\n");
            } else if (filePath.endsWith(".jpg")) {
                dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-type: image/jpeg\r\n");
            } else if (filePath.endsWith("gif")) {
                dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-type: image/gif\r\n");
            } else if (filePath.endsWith("css")) {
                dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-type: text/css\r\n");
            }
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes("\r\n");
            // Read content at 1KB rate.
            File file = new File(filePath);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[(int)file.length()];
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            int size = fis.read(buffer);
            while (size > 0) {
                dataOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, size);
                size = fis.read(buffer);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Unable to READ/WRITE: "  + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private static void invalidRequestErr() throws IOException {
        String errorMessage = "This Web Server only demonstrates GET or POST requests\r\n";
        dataOutputStream.writeBytes("HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\n");
        dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-length: " + errorMessage.length() + "\r\n\r\n");
        dataOutputStream.writeBytes(errorMessage);
    }

    private static void fileNotFoundError(String fileName) throws IOException {
        String errorMessage = "Unable to find " + fileName + " on this server.\r\n";
        dataOutputStream.writeBytes("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\r\n");
        dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-length: " + errorMessage.length() + "\r\n\r\n");
        dataOutputStream.writeBytes(errorMessage);
    }

    private static void forbiddenAccessError(String fileName) throws IOException {
        String errorMessage = "You need permission to access " + fileName + " on this server.\r\n";
        dataOutputStream.writeBytes("HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden\r\n");
        dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-length: " + errorMessage.length() + "\r\n\r\n");
        dataOutputStream.writeBytes(errorMessage);
    }
}

class HTTPRequestParser {

    private String requestMethod, fileName, queryString, formData;
    private Hashtable<String, String> headers;
    private int[] ver;

    public HTTPRequestParser(InputStream is) {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        requestMethod = "";
        fileName = "";
        queryString = "";
        formData = "";
        headers = new Hashtable<String, String>();
        try {
            // Wait for HTTP request from the connection
            String line = br.readLine();

            // Bail out if line is null. In case some client tries to be 
            // funny and close immediately after connection.  (I am
            // looking at you, Chrome!)
            if (line == null) {
                return;
            }

            // Shows Client requests in server log.
            System.out.println("Request: " + line);

            String tokens[] = line.split(" ");

            requestMethod = tokens[0];

            if (tokens[1].contains("?")) {
                String urlComponents[] = tokens[1].split("\\?");
                fileName = urlComponents[0];
                queryString = urlComponents[1];
            } else {
                fileName = tokens[1];
            }

            // Read/Parse HTTP headers
            int idx;
            line = br.readLine();
            while (!line.equals("")) {
                idx = line.indexOf(":");
                if (idx < 0) {
                    headers = null;
                    break;
                } else {
                    headers.put(line.substring(0, idx).toLowerCase(),
                            line.substring(idx+1).trim());
                }
                line = br.readLine();
            }

            // Read POST Data
            if (requestMethod.equals("POST")) {
                int contentLength = getContentLength();
                final char[] data = new char[contentLength];
                for (int i = 0; i < contentLength; i++) {
                    data[i] = (char) br.read();
                }
                formData = new String(data);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Unable to READ | WRITE: "  + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public String getRequestMethod() {
        return requestMethod;
    }

    public String getFileName() {
        return fileName;
    }

    public String getQueryString() {
        return queryString;
    }

    public String getContentType() {
        return headers.get("content-type");
    }

    public int getContentLength() {
        return Integer.parseInt(headers.get("content-length"));
    }

    public String getFormData() {
        return formData;
    }

    public static List<File> fileList(String directoryName) {
        File directory = new File(directoryName);

        List<File> resultList = new ArrayList<File>();

        // get all the files from the directory
        File[] fileList = directory.listFiles();
        for(File file : fileList) {
            if (file.isFile()) {
                System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
            } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
                resultList.addAll(fileList(file.getAbsolutePath()));
            }
        }
        return resultList;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the "landing page" you said is the root path in URL(/), as same as the `WEB_ROOT` in your code. This situation was perfectly handled, so no need to worry about.
The only problem here is how to produce a list of subfolders or files as a webpage. You need use Java code to get a list of folders and files, then composing them to HTML code. Like you did in `fileList` method.
HTML is a type of markup language. To construct it, just insert HTML markups to a string, then send it through HTTP like a file.
The simple syntax of `<a>` tag is:`<a href="path">display content</a>`, this file server relies on relative path, so we need to calculate the relative path between the root path and the file/subfolder path, and we will adding a "/" before the relative path to declare that this is a relative path base on host(http://localhost:port).
Here's a simple code which can produce this:

```
private static void folderRequests(File folder) {
    try {
        dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-type: text/html\r\n");
        dataOutputStream.writeBytes("\r\n");

        dataOutputStream.writeBytes("<html><body>"); // html open tag
        for (File file : folder.listFiles()) {
            // calculate relative path
            Path rootPath = Paths.get(new File(WEB_ROOT).toURI()); // this can be static
            Path filePath = Paths.get(file.toURI());
            String pathString = rootPath.relativize(filePath).toString();

            // construct html
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes("<a href=\"/" + pathString + "\">"
                    + file.getName() + "</a><br>");
        }
        dataOutputStream.writeBytes("</body></html>"); // html close tag
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Replace `staticFileRequests(filePath);` to:

```
if (file.isDirectory()) {
    folderRequests(file);
} else {
    staticFileRequests(filePath);
}
```

Note that there several problem you may want care:
- Some folders contains space, I'm so lazy so I ignore encoding while formatting as HTML(you can do it explicitly by using class `URLEncoder`).But, while handling requests, if there's a folder named "A folder", the browser will access "http://localhost:port/a%20folder" instead of "http://localhost:port/a folder". You need to add some code to deal with it. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding for more information.
- You may want using UTF-8 charset for supporting more characters. 
- For calculating relative path, see: [How to construct a relative path in Java from two absolute paths (or URLs)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204784/how-to-construct-a-relative-path-in-java-from-two-absolute-paths-or-urls)

Comment: I am receiving a "Connection accepted.
Unable to read/write: Software caused connection abort: socket write error" in my console log. I don't know if the server is being permitted access by my system to work the way that its supposed to. Can you try to run the code and see if you're able to get the correct responses from the webserver?

Comment: @JohnnyC Mine copy is working well. Note that I'm using Windows so I modified WEB_ROOT.

Comment: I'm using windows as well. What would be the best string to use for the WEB_ROOT. That may be the issue.

Comment: @JohnnyC I just use "D:" as WEB_ROOT, I tried "" and "." both are also working good. I did that for solving "Access denied" problem. Also I run it by Intellj IDEA. You'd better remove code in the answer to see if my code have any problem.

Comment: Its working perfectly now. I had to remove the old file method that I wrote at the bottom!