# How to write the equivalent of python's os.path.relpath() in java or groovy

Tags: java, python, groovy, path

If I have a path /a/b/c/d/e and I want to remove some of the path from the root  - for example remove /a/b/c from it to get just /d/e it is very simple in python:

```
os.path.relpath("/a/b/c/d/e", "/a/b/c")
```

The question is how to accomplish this in java.
The best idea I have come up with so far is to create a Path for each, create an iterator, loop on it and create a Path array.
Then check the size of each of the arrays (5 and 3 in the above example) and then rebuild the path from the 4th location ...
very cumbersome..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204784/how-to-construct-a-relative-path-in-java-from-two-absolute-paths-or-urls

Answer (score 0):

In Groovy:

```
def rootPath = new File('/a/b')
def fullPath = new File('/a/b/c/d')

def relPath = new File(root.toURI().relativize(full.toURI()).toString())
```

[Source](https://gist.github.com/ysb33r/5804364)